# How do I view 'git diff' output with my preferred diff tool/ viewer?

Tags: git, diff, difftool, git-difftool, diffmerge

When I type `git diff`, I want to view the output with my visual diff tool of choice (SourceGear "diffmerge" on Windows). How do I configure git to do this?

Comment: You can use "git difftool" instead of "git diff" in all newer versions of git. That will open up a visual diff program.

Comment: Regarding the new script difftool, I have added an answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-visual-diff-program/949242#949242

Comment: gitx - http://gitx.frim.nl/. Nuff said.

Comment: Brief tutorial you'd find here: http://nathanhoad.net/how-to-meld-for-git-diffs-in-ubuntu-hardy

Comment: `git difftool -tool=opendiff` just replace `opendiff` with whatever.

Comment: Go to your repository in Git Bash. Type `git config diff.tool winmerge`. Verify it worked by typing `git difftool`. Get rid of the prompt typing `git config --global difftool.prompt false`. I recommend p4merge instead of winmerge.

Comment: **(1.) to list supported external diff tools do `git difftool --tool-help` (2.) to open using a specific diff tool like `vimdiff` just do `git difftool --tool=vimdiff`.** This is a summary of [the solution written by @JakubNarębski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901386/52074)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069490/git-diff-with-beyond-compare/69659063#69659063, and just replace the path to beyond compare with the path to your tool.

Answer (score 417, accepted):

Since Git1.6.3, you can use the **git difftool script**: see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-visual-diff-program/949242#949242).

---

May be this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170508180316/http://git.net:80/ml/version-control.msysgit/2008-06/msg00200.html) will help you. Here are the best parts:

There are two different ways to specify an external diff tool.

The first is the method you used, by setting the GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF variable. However, the variable is supposed to point to the full path of the executable. Moreover, the executable specified by GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF will be called with a fixed set of 7 arguments:

```
path old-file old-hex old-mode new-file new-hex new-mode
```

As most diff tools will require a different order (and only some) of the arguments, you will most likely have to specify a wrapper script instead, which in turn calls the real diff tool.

The second method, which I prefer, is to **configure the external diff tool via "git
config"**. Here is what I did:

1) Create a wrapper script "git-diff-wrapper.sh" which contains something like

```
-->8-(snip)--
#!/bin/sh

# diff is called by git with 7 parameters:
# path old-file old-hex old-mode new-file new-hex new-mode

"<path_to_diff_executable>" "$2" "$5" | cat
--8<-(snap)--
```

As you can see, only the second ("old-file") and fifth ("new-file") arguments will be
passed to the diff tool.

2) Type

```
$ git config --global diff.external <path_to_wrapper_script>
```

at the command prompt, replacing  with the path to "git-diff-wrapper.sh", so your ~/.gitconfig contains

```
-->8-(snip)--
[diff]
    external = <path_to_wrapper_script>
--8<-(snap)--
```

Be sure to use the correct syntax to specify the paths to the wrapper script and diff
tool, i.e. use forward slashed instead of backslashes. In my case, I have

```
[diff]
    external = \"c:/Documents and Settings/sschuber/git-diff-wrapper.sh\"
```

in .gitconfig and

```
"d:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 3/BCompare.exe" "$2" "$5" | cat
```

in the wrapper script. Mind the trailing "cat"!

(I suppose the '`| cat`' is needed only for some programs which may not return a proper or consistent return status. You might want to try without the trailing cat if your diff tool has explicit return status)

([Diomidis Spinellis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20520/diomidis-spinellis) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-my-preferred-diff-tool-viewer/255212#comment96247087_255212):

> The `cat` command is required, because [`diff(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html), by default exits with an error code if the files differ.
>   Git expects the external diff program to exit with an error code only if an actual error occurred, e.g. if it run out of memory.
>   By piping the output of `git` to `cat` the non-zero error code is masked.
>   More efficiently, the program could just run `exit` with and argument of 0.)

---

That (the article quoted above) is the theory for external tool **defined through config file** (not through environment variable).
In practice (still for config file definition of external tool), you can refer to:

- [How do I setup DiffMerge with msysgit / gitk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780425/how-do-i-setup-diffmerge-with-msysgit-gitk/783667#783667) which illustrates the concrete settings of DiffMerge and WinMerge for MsysGit and gitk
- [How can I set up an editor to work with Git on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows/773973#773973) for the definition of Notepad++ as an external editor.

Comment: ah,  I'd set the external diff program but didn't know about the 7 arguments, thanks.

Comment: Kudos ... this is very handy.  I set this up with "opendiff" (which launches the slick XCode FileMerge utility under Mac OS X).

Comment: @Ryan: that is great :) Did you use the "diff.external" setting detailed in this answer or the "git difftool" of my second answer below?

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you, tried both DiffMerge and opendiff; both work quite well.

Comment: `old-file old-hex old-mode new-file new-hex new-mode` that's only 6 arguments, not 7...

Comment: @Jez: yes that article omit the first argument, which is the path. You will find it though a few line below.

Comment: So git sends 7 arguments to a diff program? The more I learn about Git, the more I feel it is was made for one person: The original programmer. This dvcs seems more like a shiny toy that doesn't do much.

Comment: @user3891 is there an alternate link to the article you referenced, that one is no longer reachable on the web

Comment: @PeterNimmo I have found an alternative link: http://osdir.com/ml/version-control.msysgit/2008-06/msg00200.html

Comment: @VonC The alternative link in your comment is also no longer accessible

Comment: @Ben Thank you. I have edited the answer and restored the link to https://web.archive.org/web/20170508180316/http://git.net:80/ml/version-control.msysgit/2008-06/msg00200.html

Comment: @JesseRusak The cat command is required, because diff(1), by default exits with an error code if the files differ.  Git expects the external diff program to exit with an error code only if an actual error occurred, e.g. if it run out of memory. By piping the output of git to cat the non-zero error code is masked. More efficiently, the program could just run exit with and argument of 0.

Comment: @DiomidisSpinellis Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Note: step 2 (modifying diff.external) will cause "git diff" to launch your difftool. This can be undesirable, and can cause problems with user interfaces (like SourceTree), causing them to aggressively launch your tool at odd times. It's probably better to modify diff.tool instead (e.g.: git config --global diff.tool p4merge)

Comment: @KevinMeboe I agree: that is what my second answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/949242/6309) proposes.

Comment: @C.J. I don't understand what is wrong with sending as much information as possible to a third-party program (i.e., not under the control of the first-party program, not known ahead of time, and any one of infinite possible choices). Assuming you're complaining about the number of arguments... although that's not quite clear either.

Answer (score 227):

To complete my previous ["diff.external" config answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-visual-diff-program/255212#255212) above:

As [mentioned by Jakub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-visual-diff-program/901386#901386), Git1.6.3 introduced [git **difftool**](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=123025539212603&w=2), originally proposed in September 2008:

USAGE=`'[--tool=tool] [--commit=ref] [--start=ref --end=ref] [--no-prompt] [file to merge]'`
(See `--extcmd` in the last part of this answer)

`$LOCAL` contains the contents of the file from the starting revision and `$REMOTE` contains the contents of the file in the ending revision.
`$BASE` contains the contents of the file in the wor

> It's basically `git-mergetool` modified to operate on the git index/worktree.
>
> The usual use case for this script is when you have either staged or unstaged changes and you'd like to see the changes in a side-by-side diff viewer (e.g. `xxdiff`, `tkdiff`, etc).

```
git difftool [<filename>*]
```

> Another use case is when you'd like to see the same information but are comparing arbitrary commits (this is the part where the revarg parsing could be better)

```
git difftool --start=HEAD^ --end=HEAD [-- <filename>*]
```

The last use case is when you'd like to compare your current worktree to something other than HEAD (e.g. a tag)

```
git difftool --commit=v1.0.0 [-- <filename>*]
```

**Note: since Git 2.5, `git config diff.tool winmerge` is enough!**
See "[git mergetool winmerge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30699239/6309)"

And [since Git 1.7.11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10879804/6309), you have the option `--dir-diff`, in order to  to spawn external diff tools that can compare two directory hierarchies at a time after populating two temporary directories, instead of running an instance of the external tool once per a file pair.

---

Before Git 2.5:

Practical case for configuring `difftool` with your custom diff tool:

```
C:\myGitRepo>git config --global diff.tool winmerge
C:\myGitRepo>git config --global difftool.winmerge.cmd "winmerge.sh \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\""
C:\myGitRepo>git config --global difftool.prompt false
```

With winmerge.sh stored in a directory part of your PATH:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Launching WinMergeU.exe: $1 $2
"C:/Program Files/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe" -u -e "$1" "$2" -dl "Local" -dr "Remote"
```

If you have another tool (kdiff3, P4Diff, ...), create another shell script, and the appropriate `difftool.myDiffTool.cmd` config directive.
Then you can easily switch tools with the `diff.tool` config.

You have also this [blog entry by Dave](http://www.davesquared.net/2009/05/setting-up-git-difftool-on-windows.html) to add other details.
(Or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2468230/6309) for the `winmergeu` options)

The interest with this setting is the **`winmerge.sh`script**: you can customize it to take into account special cases.

See for instance [David Marble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216735/david-marble)'s [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-visual-diff-program/4116806#4116806) for an example which deals with:

- *new* files in either origin or destination
- *removed* files in either origin or destination

---

As [Kem Mason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/398582/kem-mason) mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-visual-diff-program/4881489#4881489), you can also **avoid any wrapper by using the `--extcmd` option**:

```
--extcmd=<command>
```

> Specify a custom command for viewing diffs. `git-difftool` ignores the configured defaults and runs **`$command $LOCAL $REMOTE`** when this option is specified.

For instance, this is how [`gitk` is able to run/use any `diff` tool](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-gitk-Use-git-difftool-for-external-diffs-td4810847.html).

Comment: I had to escape the $, for $LOCAL and $REMOTE to prevent them from becoming "" and "".
I would edit to say
git config --globla difftool.winmerge.cmd "winmerge.sh \"\$LOCAL\" \"\$REMOTE\""

Comment: Also, any idea of how to get the -s option (open several diffs in one winmerge window) to work in this scheme?

Comment: @Frank: I confirm, the `$PATH` or `%PATH%` is respected when it comes to `git config` directives (what is your setup? Git Version? OS?). And if you want to signal a post to Carlos, your comment needs to begin with '`@`': @Carlos (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have/35913#35913)

Comment: @Carlos: Frank (see comment above) wanted you to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220309/git-difftool-open-all-diff-files-immediately-not-in-serial/1291578 (for opening several diffs in one winmerge window)

Comment: the path issue I had was resolved, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664283/msysgit-bash-shell-how-to-troubleshoot-cannot-find-command/2664382#2664382

Comment: Note: git difftool now support directory diffs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113889/git-difftool-to-give-directory-compare/2115188#2115188

Comment: The `--start=` and `--end=` options are not recognised in v1.7.11

Comment: @VonC What does the option `-ub` do? I don't see it as one of the [command line options of WinMerge](http://manual.winmerge.org/Command_line.html).

Comment: Also worth mentioning the highly useful `--dir-diff` option in order to compare all the files at once and avoid prompts.

Comment: @SteveChambers Yes, I mentioned it in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10879804/6309. I will edit this answer.

Answer (score 121):

Try this solution:

```
$ meld my_project_using_git
```

[Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) understands Git and provides navigating around the recent changes.

Comment: That's great, much easier to type `meld .` than `git difftool` and have to view changed files sequentially. And it's much closer to Mercurial's `hg vdiff` plugin.

Comment: Also, `meld .` works on Mercurial and Subversion projects too, in case anyone is curious.

Comment: Hmm, when I do this a list of modified files shows. When I click on one of them or do 'compare' it opens alone in a separate tab. How do I get a diff?

Comment: @misiu_mp, I just tried it, on clicking the modified files, it shows the diff (old file as well as modified file).

Comment: At what version was this added? It doesn't appear to work with meld version `1.1.5`.

Comment: Only one drawback: sometimes meld can scan diffs much longer than through using difftool. Looks like it still scans gitignored files (lots of build generated files in my case). It took several seconds on my machine to create a list of modified files, but with difftool it happened instantly

Comment: Is there the same feature for kompare? I liked this solution very much (especially, that it allows you to select interested file from a list).

Comment: That's excellent if you want to see current changes. I found `git difftool -y -t meld --dir-diff other_branch` to be useful too, to see the difference with any branch.

Answer (score 52):

With new git *difftool*, its as simple as adding this to your *.gitconfig* file:

```
[diff]
    tool = any-name
[difftool "any-name"]
    cmd = "\"C:/path/to/my/ext/diff.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\""
```

Optionally, also add:

```
[difftool]
    prompt = false
```

[Also check out ***diffall***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220309/git-difftool-open-all-diff-files-immediately-not-in-serial/1291578#1291578), a simple script I wrote to extend the annoying (IMO) default diff behaviour of opening each in serial.

Global .gitconfig on Windows is in `%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig`

Comment: what is $local and what is $remote?

Comment: +1 for a method that doesn't require a wrapper script

Comment: @CJohnson: Path to the original file and path to the edited file, respectively.

Comment: in case the blog-link dies, here's the linked SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1291578/321973

Comment: @CJohnson: $LOCAL is always the latest commit. However $REMOTE isn't consistent. When looking at changes in the local sandbox, it's the current/edited file, But when diffing historical commits, it's the _parent_ commit. IOW for normal diffs $LOCAL = old and $REMOTE = new. For historical, $LOCAL = newer and $REMOTE = older.

Answer (score 45):

Since Git version 1.6.3 there is "**[git difftool](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-difftool.html)**" which you can configure to use your favorite graphical diff tool.

Currently supported (at the time of writing this answer) out-of-the-box are *[KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/), [Kompare](https://apps.kde.org/kompare/), [tkdiff](https://tkdiff.sourceforge.io/), [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/), [xxdiff](http://furius.ca/xxdiff/), emerge, vimdiff, gvimdiff, ecmerge, [Diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/index.html)* and *opendiff*; if the tool you want to use isn't on this list, you can always use '`difftool.<tool>.cmd`' configuration option.

"git difftool" accepts the same options as "git diff".

Comment: Araxis Merge is also configured. http://www.araxis.com/merge/scm_integration.html

Comment: example usage: `git difftool -t kdiff3 HEAD`

Answer (score 28):

I have one addition to this.  I like to regularly use a diff app that isn't supported as one of the default tools (e.g. kaleidoscope), via

```
git difftool -t
```

I also like to have the default `diff` just be the regular command line, so setting the `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` variable isn't an option.

You can use an arbitrary `diff` app as a one-off with this command:

```
git difftool --extcmd=/usr/bin/ksdiff
```

It just passes the 2 files to the command you specify, so you probably don't need a wrapper either.

Comment: Good point: nobody has mentioned yet that `--extcmd` option. +1. I have included it in my answer.

Comment: Can you add a reference to "kaleidoscope"?

Answer (score 24):

Building on [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-my-preferred-diff-tool-viewer/255212#255212) to deal with file removals and additions, use the following commands and scripts:

```
git config --global diff.tool winmerge
git config --global difftool.winmerge.cmd "winmerge.sh \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$BASE\""
git config --global difftool.prompt false
```

Which is the same as putting this in your global file *.gitconfig*:

```
[diff]
    tool = winmerge
[difftool "winmerge"]
    cmd = winmerge.bat "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$BASE"
[difftool]
    prompt = false
```

Then put the following in file *winmerge.sh* which must be on your path:

```
#!/bin/sh
NULL="/dev/null"
if [ "$2" = "$NULL" ] ; then
    echo "removed: $3"
elif [ "$1" = "$NULL" ] ; then
    echo "added: $3"
else
    echo "changed: $3"
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe" -e -ub -dl "Base" -dr "Mine" "$1" "$2"
fi
```

Comment: Excellent addition to the `winmerge.sh` script. +1. I have updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-visual-diff-program/949242#949242) to link to yours.

Comment: `winmerge.bat` in the second snippet should be `winmerge.sh`

Comment: Can you make this for many tools ? And associate them by file extension ?

Answer (score 12):

### Solution for Windows/[MSYS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW#History) Git

After reading the answers, I discovered a simpler way that involves changing only one file.

1. Create a batch file to invoke your diff program, with argument 2 and 5. This file must be somewhere in your path. (If you don't know where that is, put it in *C:\windows*.) Call it, for example, "gitdiff.bat". Mine is:

   ```
   @echo off
   REM This is gitdiff.bat
   "C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe" %2 %5
   ```
2. Set the environment variable to point to your batch file. For example:`GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=gitdiff.bat`. Or through PowerShell by typing `git config --global diff.external gitdiff.bat`.

   It is important to not use quotes, or specify any path information, otherwise it won't work. That's why *gitdiff.bat* must be in your path.

Now when you type "git diff", it will invoke your external diff viewer.

Comment: +1 (+10 if I could.) This is really the most simple solution. I struggled for hours with the accepted answer, and finally gave up (some of my problems were probably related to running Git through PowerShell...) However, I used `git config --global diff.external winmerge.cmd`, instead of setting the `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` environment variable, and it works equally well.

Comment: A couple of issues with this solution:

1. Doesn't work for new files. WinMerge asks me to enter a second file to compare against. 

2. Window to compare next file only opens up after you close the current WinMerge window, no easy way to see all files at the same time.

Answer (score 10):

If you're doing this through [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin), you may need to use **cygpath**:

```
$ git config difftool.bc3.cmd "git-diff-bcomp-wrapper.sh \$LOCAL \$REMOTE"
$ cat git-diff-bcomp-wrapper.sh
#!/bin/sh
"c:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/BComp.exe" `cygpath -w $1` `cygpath -w $2`
```

Comment: For some reason, using "bc3" is no longer working for me, but if I use "beyond" instead, it's fine.

Answer (score 9):

After looking at some other external diff tools, I found that the `diff` view in IntelliJ IDEA (and Android Studio) is the best one for me.

## Step 1 - setup IntelliJ IDEA to be run from the command line

If you want to use IntelliJ IDEA as your diff tool you should first setup IntelliJ IDEA to be run from the command line following the instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-intellij-idea-as-a-diff-or-merge-command-line-tool.html):

**On macOS or UNIX:**

1. Make sure IntelliJ IDEA is running.
2. On the main menu, choose `Tools | Create Command-line Launcher`. The dialog box Create Launcher Script opens, with the suggested path and name of the launcher script. You can accept default, or specify your own path.
   Make notice of it, as you'll need it later.
   Outside of IntelliJ IDEA, add the path and name of the launcher script to your path.

**On Windows:**

1. Specify the location of the IntelliJ IDEA executable in the Path system environment variable. In this case, you will be able to invoke the IntelliJ IDEA executable and other IntelliJ IDEA commands from any directory.

## Step 2 - configure git to use IntelliJ IDEA as the difftool

Following the instructions on [this blog post](http://brian.pontarelli.com/2013/10/25/using-idea-for-git-merging-and-diffing/):

**Bash**

```
export INTELLIJ_HOME /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ CE.app/Contents/MacOS
PATH=$IDEA_HOME $PATH
```

**Fish**

```
set INTELLIJ_HOME /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ CE.app/Contents/MacOS
set PATH $INTELLIJ_HOME $PATH
```

Now add the following to your git config:

```
[merge]
   tool = intellij
[mergetool "intellij"]
   cmd = idea merge $(cd $(dirname "$LOCAL") && pwd)/$(basename "$LOCAL") $(cd $(dirname "$REMOTE") && pwd)/$(basename "$REMOTE") $(cd $(dirname "$BASE") && pwd)/$(basename "$BASE") $(cd $(dirname "$MERGED") && pwd)/$(basename "$MERGED")
   trustExitCode = true
[diff]
   tool = intellij
[difftool "intellij"]
   cmd = idea diff $(cd $(dirname "$LOCAL") && pwd)/$(basename "$LOCAL") $(cd $(dirname "$REMOTE") && pwd)/$(basename "$REMOTE")
```

You can try it out with `git difftool` or `git difftool HEAD~1`

Answer (score 8):

This works for me on Windows 7. There isn't any need for intermediary *[sh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)* scripts

Contents of .gitconfig:

```
    [diff]
      tool = kdiff3

    [difftool]
       prompt = false

    [difftool "kdiff3"]
      path = C:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
      cmd = "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

Comment: Do you also have kdiff3 defined as your mergetool?  Mind sharing that part of your gitconfig if so?

Comment: Thanks. This didn't quite work for me but it did work when I removed `path` and changed `cmd` to `"\"C:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\""`

Answer (score 8):

A short summary of the previous great answers:

```
git difftool --tool-help
git config --global diff.tool <chosen tool>
git config --global --add difftool.prompt false
```

Then use it by typing (optionally specifying the file name as well):

```
git difftool
```

Answer (score 7):

Install [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/):

```
 # apt-get install meld
```

Then choose that as the difftool:

```
 $ git config --global diff.tool meld
```

If you want to run it in the console, type:

```
 $ git difftool
```

If you want to use graphic mode, type:

```
 $ git mergetool
```

And the output would be:

```
 'git mergetool' will now attempt to use one of the following tools:
 meld opendiff kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff tortoisemerge gvimdiff diffuse
 diffmerge ecmerge p4merge araxis bc3 codecompare emerge vimdiff
 Merging:
 www/css/style.css
 www/js/controllers.js

 Normal merge conflict for 'www/css/style.css':
   {local}: modified file
   {remote}: modified file
 Hit return to start merge resolution tool (meld):
```

So just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to use meld (default). This would open graphic mode. Make the magic save and press that that resolve the merge. That's all.

Comment: I love meld but it has been behaving very poorly on MacOs, so I've switched to sublime merge.

Answer (score 6):

### Introduction

For reference I'd like to include my variation on [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-my-preferred-diff-tool-viewer/255212#255212). Keep in mind that I am using the MSys version of Git (1.6.0.2 at this time) with modified PATH, and running Git itself from PowerShell (or cmd.exe), not the Bash shell.

I introduced a new command, `gitdiff`. Running this command temporarily redirects `git diff` to use a visual diff program of your choice (as opposed to VonC's solution that does it permanently). This allows me to have both the default Git diff functionality (`git diff`) as well as visual diff functionality (`gitdiff`). Both commands take the same parameters, so for example to visually diff changes in a particular file you can type

```
gitdiff path/file.txt
```

### Setup

Note that `$GitInstall` is used as a placeholder for the directory where Git is installed.

1. Create a new file, `$GitInstall\cmd\gitdiff.cmd`

   ```
    @echo off
    setlocal
    for /F "delims=" %%I in ("%~dp0..") do @set path=%%~fI\bin;%%~fI\mingw\bin;%PATH%
    if "%HOME%"=="" @set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
    set GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=git-diff-visual.cmd
    set GIT_PAGER=cat
    git diff %*
    endlocal
   ```
2. Create a new file, `$GitInstall\bin\git-diff-visual.cmd` (replacing `[visual_diff_exe]` placeholder with full path to the diff program of your choice)

   ```
    @echo off
    rem diff is called by git with 7 parameters:
    rem path old-file old-hex old-mode new-file new-hex new-mode
    echo Diffing "%5"
    "[visual_diff_exe]" "%2" "%5"
    exit 0
   ```
3. You're now done. Running `gitdiff` from within a Git repository should now invoke your visual diff program for every file that was changed.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a batch file that works for Windows - assumes DiffMerge installed in default location, handles x64, handles forward to backslash replacement as necessary and has ability to install itself.  Should be easy to replace DiffMerge with your favourite diff program.

To install:

```
gitvdiff --install
```

gitvdiff.bat:

```
@echo off

REM ---- Install? ----
REM To install, run gitvdiff --install

if %1==--install goto install



REM ---- Find DiffMerge ----

if DEFINED ProgramFiles^(x86^) (
    Set DIFF="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\SourceGear\DiffMerge\DiffMerge.exe"
) else (
    Set DIFF="%ProgramFiles%\SourceGear\DiffMerge\DiffMerge.exe"
)



REM ---- Switch forward slashes to back slashes ----

set oldW=%2
set oldW=%oldW:/=\%
set newW=%5
set newW=%newW:/=\%


REM ---- Launch DiffMerge ----

%DIFF% /title1="Old Version" %oldW% /title2="New Version" %newW%

goto :EOF



REM ---- Install ----
:install
set selfL=%~dpnx0
set selfL=%selfL:\=/%
@echo on
git config --global diff.external %selfL%
@echo off


:EOF
```

Comment: Great script, it saved me the trouble of looking DiffMerge commands.  You might want to modify the install line to use quotes - I had trouble on my machine:  "%1"=="--install".

Answer (score 6):

If you're on a Mac and have [Xcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode), then you have [FileMerge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Developer_Tools#FileMerge) installed. The terminal command is opendiff, so you can just do:

```
git difftool -t opendiff
```

Comment: Use the -y option to avoid annoying prompts.  Unfortunately, git will wait until FileMerge quits before offering the next changed file.  Use the -d option to do a directory compare in one shot.

Comment: The option -t seems to require the complete path. Maybe using git difftool --extcmd=opendiff is better.

Answer (score 5):

For a Linux version of how to configure a diff tool on Git versions prior to 1.6.3 (1.6.3 added difftool to Git), [this](http://technotales.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/git-diff-with-vimdiff/) is a great concise tutorial.

In brief:

Step 1: add this to your .gitconfig

```
[diff]
  external = git_diff_wrapper
[pager]
  diff =
```

Step 2: create a file named git_diff_wrapper, put it somewhere in your $PATH

```
#!/bin/sh

vimdiff "$2" "$5"
```

Answer (score 4):

On Mac OS X,

```
git difftool -t diffuse
```

does the job for me in the Git folder. For installing [Diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/index.html), one can use port -

```
sudo port install diffuse
```

Comment: "port"? On [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution)?

Comment: Can you add references to 'port' and 'diffuse'? And presumed platforms/operating system(s)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `git difftool`.

For example, if you have [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/), you can edit the branches `master` and `devel` by:

```
git config --global diff.external meld
git difftool master..devel
```

Answer (score 3):

The following can be gleaned from the other answers here, but for me it's difficult, (too much information), so here's the 'just type it in' answer for tkdiff:

```
git difftool --tool=tkdiff <path to the file to be diffed>
```

You can substitute the executable name of your favorite diffing tool for tkdiff.  As long as (e.g. tkdiff), (or your favorite diffing tool) is in your PATH, it will be launched.

Comment: this is the simplest and fastest way.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the fancy stuff here (with tkdiff) and nothing worked for me.  So I wrote the following script, tkgitdiff.  It does what I need it to do.

```
$ cat tkgitdiff
#!/bin/sh

#
# tkdiff for git.
# Gives you the diff between HEAD and the current state of your file.
#

newfile=$1
git diff HEAD -- $newfile > /tmp/patch.dat
cp $newfile /tmp
savedPWD=$PWD
cd /tmp
patch -R $newfile < patch.dat
cd $savedPWD
tkdiff /tmp/$newfile $newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [Kompare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kompare) on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install kompare
```

To compare two branches:

```
git difftool -t kompare <my_branch> master
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this bit in file `~/.gitconfig` for a long time:

```
[diff]
    external = ~/Dropbox/source/bash/git-meld
```

With `git-meld`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$DISPLAY" = "" ];
then
    diff $2 $5
else
    meld $2 $5
fi
```

But now I got tired of always using [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) in a graphical environment, and it's not trivial to invoke the normal diff with this setup, so I switched to this:

```
[alias]
    v =  "!sh -c 'if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then git difftool -y -t meld ; else git difftool -y $@ ; fi' -"
```

With this setup, things like this work:

```
git v
git v --staged
git v -t kompare
git v --staged -t tkdiff
```

And I still get to keep the good old `git diff`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try out [xd](http://github.com/jiqingtang/xd), which is a GUI wrapper for Git/SVN diff. It is *not* a diff tool itself.

You run `xd` when you want to run `git diff` or `svn diff` and it will show you a list of files, a preview window and you can launch any diff tool you like, including tkdiff, xxdiff, gvimdiff, Emacs (ediff), [XEmacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XEmacs) (ediff), [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/), [Diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/index.html), [Kompare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kompare) and [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/). You can also run any custom tool.

Unfortunately the tool doesn't support Windows.

**Disclosure**: I am the author of this tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to already have a diff tool associated with filetypes (say, because you installed TortoiseSVN which comes with a diff viewer) you could just pipe the regular `git diff` output to a "temp" file, then just open that file directly without needing to know anything about the viewer:

```
git diff > "~/temp.diff" && start "~/temp.diff"
```

Setting it as a global alias works even better: `git what`

```
[alias]
    what = "!f() { git diff > "~/temp.diff" && start "~/temp.diff"; }; f"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not one for the command line then if you install [TortoiseGit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseGit), you can right click on a file to get a TortoiseGit submenu with the "Diff later" option.

When you select this on the first file, you can then right click on the second file, go to the TortoiseGit submenu and select "Diff with ==yourfilehere==".
This will give the TortoiseGit merge GUI for the result.