# Msys Git Merge Tool Command Options Issue

Tags: git, version-control, merge, batch-file

I'm using [msys Git](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) for source control on a Windows machine and I'm trying to figure out how to get my merge tool, [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/), to work with Git.

I've followed [the instructions on this blog](http://davesquared.blogspot.com/2009/02/setting-up-diff-and-merge-tools-for-git.html) to the best of my ability since it's the closest I've found to what I'm trying to do. Basically what I did was:

Modify my `.gitconfig` file to include the following:

```
[merge]
    tool = winmerge

[mergetool "winmerge"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinMerge\\WinMergeU.exe\" "$PWD/$LOCAL" "$PWD/$REMOTE" "$PWD/$MERGED"  
        trustExitCode = false  
    keepBackup = false
```

This is almost working. When I try to run the merge tool from Git, WinMerge gives me an error saying it can't find the paths of the files, which makes complete sense since the paths it is looking for are:

```
C:\MY\WORKING\DIRECTORY\-e
C:\MY\WORKING\DIRECTORY\-ub
```

It looks like Git is passing options into the merge tool instead of the local & remote file names that I would expect to get passed if everything was working correctly.

I've searched online for Git's merge documentation, but I can't seem to find anything related to what I'm trying to do. My guess is that the solution will be one of the following:

1. Change the `$LOCAL` & `$REMOTE` variables to the correct values, assuming `$LOCAL` & `$REMOTE` are incorrect.
2. Write a `.bat` script to call WinMergeU, and handle the arguments Git sends to the merge tool within the logic of my `.bat` script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [WinMerge Command line manual](http://winmerge.org/docs/manual/CommandLine.html):

```
cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinMerge\\WinMergeU.exe /ub /e \"
cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinMerge\\WinMergeU.exe /u /e \"
```

(/u is the new /ub with latest WinMerge)

might work better as a command in your mergetool section.

However, you might have to wrap this call in a script, as described in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-visual-diff-program/392899#392899).

Extract adapted to `merge.tool`:

> Practical case for configuring `mergetool` with your custom `diff` tool:

```
C:\myGitRepo>git config --global merge.tool winmerge
C:\myGitRepo>git config --global mergetool.winmerge.cmd "winmerge.sh \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\""
C:\myGitRepo>git config --global mergetool.prompt false
```

With `winmerge.sh` stored in a directory part of your `PATH`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Launching WinMergeU.exe: $1 $2
"C:/Program Files/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe" -e -ub "$1" "$2"
```

> If you have another tool (`kdiff3`, `P4Diff`, ...), create another shell script, and the appropriate `mergetool.myMergeTool.cmd` config directive.
>   Then you can easily switch tools with the `merge.tool` config.

Comment: +1. (if I could. But at least I could undo my downvote... seems to be a [bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23147/change-a-vote-from-downvote-to-upvote-via-editing)) actually, if you add winmerge to your path (or set `mergetool.winmerge.path` I guess) no script is needed

Comment: by the way, it should be `mergetool`, not `difftool` for this question

Comment: @Tobias: Thank you. Answer updated (`difftool` replaced by `mergetool`)

Comment: Natch add (x86) to path if you're using x64 Windows. Tried to add an edit to show what the .gitconfig file would look like if you edited it rather than used `git config --global` three times. Key lines in your .gitconfig: Under `[merge]` (adding bracketed sections if they don't exist) add `tool = winmerge` and under `[mergetool "winmerge"]` add `cmd = "wmDiff.sh \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\""` then `trustExitCode = false` then `keepBackup = false`. Also under `[mergetool]` (no "winmerge" after; new section) is `prompt = false`. Found editing .gitconfig to be easier for testing/optimzing options.

Answer (score 12):

If you look at the file that is conflicted, you'll notice the standard `Theirs >>>>>>>` and `<<<<<< Mine` markers. WinMerge understands these as merge conflicts, so it does not need 'Theirs' and 'Mine' to be specified explicitly; it just needs to be told which file it is that has the conflict markers.

1. We know the file in the working directory contains the markers.
2. It makes sense that the file we are merging to will also be this file - we also know that `git mergetool` makes the `$MERGED` variable available that names that file.

   ```
   [mergetool "winmerge"]
       cmd = 'C:/Program Files/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe' \"$MERGED\"
   ```

This is all you need to hook git up with WinMerge for merge/conflict resolution; no scripts or command-line switches needed. Refer to the 3rd command-line form in the docs (linked by the OP, above) and the explanation of `conflictfile` argument.

Comment: There is no right path?
From the WinMerge docs  

`conflictfile Specifies a conflict file, typically generated by a Version control system. The conflict file opens in the File Compare window, where you can merge and resolve conflicts, as described in Resolving conflict files. Note that no other paths can be used with a conflict file.` (excuse the lame quoting)

Perhaps you aren't using the latest version you only need to specify one file

Comment: Glad to be of help... did you vote, lol? Am I aloud to ask that?

Comment: Added this to my .gitconfig in my home folder (C:\Users\username\ on Windows), and was off to the races! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
[mergetool "winmerge"]
    cmd = winmergeu -e -ub -wl -dl "Remote" -dr "Local" "$PWD/$REMOTE" "$PWD/$LOCAL" "$PWD/$MERGED"
    keepBackup = false
```

If you look inside `C:\Program Files\Git\share\git-gui\lib\mergetool.tcl` it has syntax for common merge tools.

I'm still trying to figure out how to invoke mergetool directly from Git GUI...