# How merge resource files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, git, resources

What is the best merge tool for Visual Studio .rc files? It would be nice, if the merge tool could display the resource (e.g. dialog box).

Comment: @Hans Passant: In this case [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) could be better.

Comment: What is the merge tool of Team Foundation Server? Is it capable to visual merge resource files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that rc files are text files, I'd go with [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) if you're on a budget, and if money's no object I'd go with [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/). The main advantage of Araxis over WinMerge is the 3-way merge.

Both are fully supported as merge tools for git.

See here for [Araxis + git](http://www.araxis.com/merge/scm_integration.html#msysGit) and here for [WinMerge + git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468230/how-to-use-winmerge-with-git-extensions).

Sadly, I know of no diff tools that would show you the resulting dialogs / controls represented by the merged file at merge time.

Answer (score 2):

These two SuperUser Questions seem to be worth a look

[What is a good text comparison tool for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/56603/what-is-a-good-text-comparison-tool-for-windows)

[What program to use to compare big files under Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/34962/what-program-to-use-to-compare-big-files-under-windows)

It seems the list they come up with is

- [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)
- [ExamDiff Pro](http://www.prestosoft.com/ps.asp?page=edp_examdiffpro)
- [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/)
- [DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/)
- [HashTab](http://implbits.com/Products.aspx)