# CVS style diffs in git

Tags: git, cvs

Is there any way to make the output format of git diffs like cvs style diffs? I find git diffs to be less readable. Also, the git diffs appearing in `more` are annoying - how can I disable this?

Comment: This really should have been two separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try playing with standard diff formatting:

```
git difftool -y -x "diff --unchanged-group-format='' --old-line-format='< %L' --new-line-format='> %L'"
```

This gives CVS-like newlines and oldlines, with no context, but it doesn't insert the extras between groups of different lines. Not quite sure how to achieve the rest, given I don't know the extent to which you would like CVS-like formatting.

```
man diff
```

For more information

Also see

```
git difftool -y -x "diff -n"
```

But I doubt this does what you want. If this does work for you, to make it work every time with git diff, see [Configuring diff tool with .gitconfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412516/configuring-diff-tool-with-gitconfig), which references http://jeetworks.com/node/90 in the accepted answer.

Comment: This combined with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331582/how-to-make-git-diff-output-normal-diff-format-non-unified-non-context gives me what I want. Cheers

Answer (score 7):

`git diff` uses the "universal" format, `diff -u`, by default.  `cvs diff` uses the older standard diff format (deleted lines marked with `<`, added lines marked with `>`, no context around each difference).

You can get a "context diff" using `git diff -c`, or `git diff -C5`, for example, to get 5 lines of context rather than the default 3.

`diff --normal` (at least if you're using GNU diffutils) will produce an old-style diff, but `git diff` doesn't seem to recognize the `--normal` option.

Personally, I find context diffs much more readable than old-style diffs, so I've never found the need to use old-style diffs with `git diff`.  Try `git diff -c` (along with haggai_e's suggestion to disable the pager).

If you really want the old-style diffs (`<`, `>`, no context), there's probably a way to do it.

**EDIT :**

If `git diff` doesn't do what you want, you can extract copies of the revisions of the file and use whatever diff tool you like on them. My own [`get-versions`](https://github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/get-versions) tool can extract multiple versions of a file from git (or from RCS or CVS).

And here's another solution, though it's a bit more complicated. As an example, I've cloned the git repo for `git` itself. If I want to compare two successive versions of the top-level `README` file, I can do this:

```
$ diff --normal <(git show 779d7e93773a0dcf918dc77023511fdc68161bd8:README) \
                <(git show 71ce415dc088f19a0b8d6c8567dfdd6d851842b2:README)
24,26c24,25
< compatible with the GPLv2).
< It was originally written by Linus Torvalds with help of a group of
< hackers around the net. It is currently maintained by Junio C Hamano.
---
> compatible with the GPLv2). It was originally written by Linus
> Torvalds with help of a group of hackers around the net.
$
```

It would be easy enough to wrap this in a small script.

Note that the file path following the `:` (`README` in the above example) is relative to the root of the repository, not to the current directory. You can precede the name with `./` to make to make it relative to the current directory. (The latter might not work with some older versions of git.)

Comment: I don't know what version of git this is pertinent to, but for "git version 1.7.7.6", git diff -c is not valid, but git diff -Un (n for number of context lines) works. git diff -U0 is almost giving me what I want, but I still don't like the appearance.

This is all a matter of preference thing really, while you prefer context diffs, I don't as it is just a sanity check before commit thing for me. If I need context diffs I'm using meld.

Cheers for the tip however. Again, I'd mark up if it would allow me to.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331582/how-to-make-git-diff-output-normal-diff-format-non-unified-non-context - here we can pass the --normal option. Cheers

Comment: @user1207217: I updated my answer (just before I read the link in the above comment).

Answer (score 5):

You can disable the pager by setting `core.pager` to an empty string:

```
git config --global core.pager ''
```

Comment: I think the usual way to do that is to set it to `cat`.

Comment: Setting it to cat does seem tidier.

Comment: @user1207217 You need some reputation before you can vote (and I can't find the link to the site explaining the reputation anymore since the last SO layout change), but  can accept the answer.