# How to make "git diff" output normal diff format (non-unified, non-context)?

Tags: git, diff

I want `git diff` to output normal, plain old diff output (not unified diff, and not context diff).

I want this:

```
$ diff file1 file2
2c2
< b
---
> B
4d3
< d
5a5
> f
```

I do NOT want unified output:

```
$ diff -u file1 file2
--- file1       2012-07-04 07:57:48.000000000 -0700
+++ file2       2012-07-04 07:58:00.000000000 -0700
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 a
-b
+B
 c
-d
 e
+f
```

I do NOT want context output:

```
$ diff -c file1 file2
*** file1       2012-07-04 07:57:48.000000000 -0700
--- file2       2012-07-04 07:58:00.000000000 -0700
***************
*** 1,5 ****
  a
! b
  c
- d
  e
--- 1,5 ----
  a
! B
  c
  e
+ f
```

I tried the various `git difftool --tool=` args with no luck, and I didn't find anything relevant in `git diff --help`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
git difftool --extcmd=diff
```

or, without prompting:

```
git difftool --extcmd=diff --no-prompt
```

This is `git difftool` rather than `git diff` but it is doing what I want.

Comment: can I ask why you need such type of data, and what is the meaning of `>` and `<`

Answer (score 2):

You can use same script (see man git(1) for details):

```
$ cat diff.sh
#!/bin/sh
# get args: path old-file old-hex old-mode new-file new-hex new-mode

diff "$2" "$5"

return=$?
if [ $return -le 1 ]; then
    exit 0
else
    exit $return
fi

$ GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=./diff.sh git diff HEAD^..HEAD
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get the error: 
  diff.sh git diff HEAD^..HEAD: 1: diff.sh git diff HEAD^..HEAD: diff.sh: not found
  external diff died, stopping at subdir/file3."  Fortunately, I found a much easier solution while googling, which I put in a separate answer.