# git diff : Fails with fatal: Unrecognized input

Tags: git, perl, diff, apply

I have a diff file which contains differences for multiple files. I want it to be applied to the current branch. So far I have tried out using `git apply changes.diff` which has failed with `fatal: Unrecognized input`. Diff file looks as follows.

```
#*#*#*DIFFS FOR FILE ./reporting/report/sso_usage_dd_report.rptdesign #*#*#*
74c74
<             <property name="odaURL">jdbc:mysql://db.mysql.domain:3306/sso_user_data</property>
---
>             <property name="odaURL">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sso_user_data</property>
#*#*#*DIFFS FOR FILE ./reporting/report/sso_usage_monthly_dd_report.rptdesign #*#*#*
67c67
<             <property name="odaURL">jdbc:mysql://db.mysql.domain:3306/sso_user_data</property>
---
>             <property name="odaURL">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sso_user_data</property>
#*#*#*DIFFS FOR FILE ./reporting/report/system_wise_access_information_report.rptdesign #*#*#*
94c94
<             <property name="odaURL">jdbc:mysql://db.mysql.domain:3306/sso_user_data</property>
---
>             <property name="odaURL">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sso_user_data</property>
```

Please note that I am unable to recreate the diff file under the current circumstances.

**Research**

Upon research I have come across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347350/all-git-patches-i-create-throw-fatal-unrecognized-input) which suggests it is a problem with `--color=never` being not set during the creation time of the patch file. I guessed the same should work with my diff file and tried out removing the color characters by using `perl -pe 's/\x1b.*?[mGKH]//g' changes.diff > changes_nocolor.diff` which didn't work.

Question is, am I on the right avenue? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this? Or is it possible for me to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That diff is not a *context diff*, but rather [what the Wikipedia entry calls *normal diff output*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility).  See also [How to make "git diff" output normal diff format (non-unified, non-context)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11331582/1256452)  Git cannot apply this non-context kind of diff.

The [patch utility](https://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) can apply normal diff output.  [There are good reasons to prefer context or unified diffs, though.](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/introduction-using-diff-and-patch/)  In particular, normal diffs can easily *mis*-apply at the wrong location, if the same line appears in more than one place of a source file.

Comment: Umm.. Is it possible to convert a normal diff to a context diff? Like you have pointed out safer way is better...

Comment: No, it's impossible to do that safely: the context you need is simply not there. You could convert it to the *form* of a context diff (with no context) but that gains nothing, except perhaps the ability to use `git apply` instead of `patch`. (But `patch` should be widely available.)

Comment: Thank you. I'll look further to apply this using `patch` command. :)