# Finding diff between current and last version

Tags: git

Using Git, how can you find the difference between the current and the last version?

```
git diff last version:HEAD
```

Comment: If you use GitHub for the cloud location of your repo it is very simple: navigate to your project and click on the heading "commits" in the table that displays your project

Comment: The meaning of "current and the last version" really should be clarified in the question.

Comment: You may want to look at this discussion too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446901/how-can-i-see-local-history-changes-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 1575, accepted):

I don't really understand the meaning of "last version".

As the previous commit can be accessed with HEAD^, I think that you are looking for something like:

```
git diff HEAD^ HEAD
```

That also can be applied for a :commithash

```
git diff $commithash^ $commithash
```

As of Git 1.8.5, `@` is an alias for `HEAD`, so you can use:

```
git diff @~..@
```

The following will also work:

```
git show
```

If you want to know the diff between head and any commit you can use:

```
git diff commit_id HEAD
```

And this will launch your visual diff tool (if configured):

```
git difftool HEAD^ HEAD
```

Since comparison to HEAD is default you can omit it (as pointed out by [Orient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26771459/5124673)):

```
git diff @^
git diff HEAD^
git diff commit_id
```

### Warnings

- @ScottF and @Panzercrisis explain in the comments that on Windows the `~` character must be used instead of `^`.

Comment: I wanted something like committed version and version before it...git diff head head-1

Comment: As of Git 1.8.5, `@` is an alias for `HEAD`. And since `~` and `^` are the same when only going one commit back, I find `git diff @~..@` much easier to type.

Comment: @Andrew `git show` is easier still, since `@~..@` is the default thing to show.

Comment: @amalloy Ah! That's right, `HEAD` is implicit for a lot of subcommands.

Comment: git difftool HEAD^ HEAD does nothing at all for me. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ScottF Do you have your difftool configured? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412516/configuring-diff-tool-with-gitconfig

Comment: `HEAD^` does not work in my case, but `HEAD~1` does, and so does `git show`.  I was thinking this may be a difference between Git 1.x and Git 2.x, but @ScottF may have found the real reason.  Maybe the answer could be edited to contain some information about this as well?

Comment: git show is absolutely useful if you just wanna get an idea of whatz goin on!

Comment: The problem with `git show` is that if `HEAD` is a merge commit you won't get what you expect since the merge commit itself may not have any changes itself. `git diff HEAD^ HEAD` will show the actual changes between the versions

Comment: Remark: For Windows Command Prompt, `^` is an escape character. Could type `^^` to represent a `^`

Comment: git diff HEAD~1 HEAD (MacOS work as expected). 
git diff HEAD^ HEAD (no matches found: HEAD^)

Comment: Zsh users should replace `HEAD^` with `'HEAD^'`

Answer (score 197):

Assuming "current version" is the working directory (uncommitted modifications) and "last version" is `HEAD` (last committed modifications for the current branch), simply do

```
git diff HEAD
```

*Credit for the following goes to user `Cerran`.*

And if you always skip the staging area with `-a` when you commit, then you can simply use `git diff`.

**Summary**

1. `git diff` shows unstaged changes.
2. `git diff --cached` shows staged changes.
3. `git diff HEAD` shows all changes (both staged and unstaged).

Source: git-diff(1) Manual Page – Cerran

Comment: And if you always skip the staging area with `-a` when you commit, then you can simply use `git diff`.

<1> **`git diff`** shows **unstaged** changes.

<2> **`git diff --cached`** shows **staged** changes.

<3> **`git diff HEAD`** shows **all** changes (both staged and unstaged).

Source: [git-diff(1) Manual Page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

Comment: What is the name of "the current unstaged version" in git? Is there actually a name?

Comment: `git diff HEAD --stat` if you're looking for the number of lines changed.

Answer (score 143):

As pointed out on a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903541/finding-diff-between-current-and-last-versions/9903611?noredirect=1#comment54037868_9903611) by [amalloy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/625403/amalloy), if by "current and last versions" you mean the last commit and the commit before that, you could simply use

```
git show
```

Comment: Use `git show HEAD~1` to show the last-but-one commit, and `git show HEAD~2`, etc. for older commits. Show just a single file via `git show HEAD~2 my_file`.

Comment: Perhaps address *[RubenLaguna's note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903541/finding-diff-between-current-and-last-version#comment87007426_9903611)* in the answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 69):

Difference between last but one commit and last commit (plus current state, if any):

```
git diff HEAD~
```

or even (easier to type)

```
git diff @~
```

where `@` is the synonim for `HEAD` of current branch and `~` means "give me the parent of mentioned revision".

Comment: I quite like `git diff HEAD^` (rather than the equivalent `HEAD~` form).  It's a tad easier to remember for an "old git" like myself ;-)

Comment: The carrot is an issue in some terminals.  Nice to have the option

Comment: Answer could be improved by explaining what the `~` and `@` mean.

Comment: If we just want to check what is committed in the last commit, don't use this (as dirty changes affect the diff). A shorter syntax to really `diff HEAD^ HEAD` should be `git diff @^!`. See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions for `r1^!`

Comment: @JohnnyWong Thank you for clarification. I mentioned "current state" to not confuse readers.

Comment: `~` is *not* easy to type on many keyboards. Isn't there a more verbose version?

Comment: @PeterMortensen you can try ^

Answer (score 63):

You can do it this way too:

Compare with the previous commit

```
git diff --name-status HEAD~1..HEAD
```

Compare with the current and previous two commits

```
git diff --name-status HEAD~2..HEAD
```

Answer (score 18):

Just use the `cached` flag if you added, but haven't committed yet:

```
git diff --cached --color
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for when I found this question. Thanks!

Comment: "cached" as a synonym for "staged"? (Or "staged changes" or *""indexed""*?)

Answer (score 14):

Quick and simple, assuming you're in the master:

```
    git diff (checkout_id):file.txt file.txt
```

Example:

```
    git diff asdfioei91819280din198:file.txt file.txt
```

Comment: Note that after the `(checkout_id):` you need a relative path to the filename from the root of the repo.  For me I tried the above from the directory the file was in, and it failed, until I changed it to
`git diff 3d44feb544150cf35b2a99d5917e294e10596f8e:./file.txt file.txt`

Also, OP's original intent isn't clear, but this answer is the only one that addresses if you want the "difference between the current and last version" OF A FILE.
I originally tried `git diff HEAD~1 -- file.txt` but it didn't work because last change to that file was 10 commits ago.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for when I found this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

If you want the changes for the last `n` commits, you can use the following:

`git diff HEAD~n`

So for the last 5 commits (count including your current commit) from the current commit, it would be:

`git diff HEAD~5`

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, use "`git log`" to list the logs for the repository.

Now, select the two commit IDs, pertaining to the two commits. You want to see the differences (**example** *- Top most commit and some older commit (as per your expectation of current-version and some old version)*).

Next, use:

```
git diff <commit_id1> <commit_id2>
```

**or**

```
git difftool <commit_id1> <commit_id2>
```

Answer (score 8):

**If the top commit is pointed to by HEAD then you can do something like this:**

```
commit1 -> HEAD
commit2 -> HEAD~1
commit3 -> HEAD~2
```

Diff between the first and second commit:

```
git diff HEAD~1 HEAD
```

Diff between first and third commit:

```
git diff HEAD~2 HEAD
```

Diff between second and third commit:

```
git diff HEAD~2 HEAD~1
```

And so on...

Answer (score 2):

I use [Bitbucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket) with the [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) IDE with the Eclipse [EGit](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit) plugin installed.

I compare a file from any version of its history (like [SVN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion)).

Menu Project Explorer → *File* → right click → *Team* → *Show in history*.

This will bring the history of all changes on that file.
Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> click and select any two versions→ *"Compare with each other"*.

Answer (score 2):

This will also work for tags (remove the 'uniq' below and other parts if you need to see all changes):

```
 git diff v1.58 HEAD
```

The below is the same, and that could be useful for [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) (CI) for microservices in a monolithic repository:

```
git diff v1.58 HEAD  --name-only | sort -u | awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"} {print $1}' | uniq
<Folder Name>
```

(Credit - https://dzone.com/articles/build-test-and-deploy-apps-independently-from-a-mo)

Answer (score 2):

to show **individual** changes in a commit, to head.

```
git show HEAD~0
```

to show **accumulated** changes in a commit, to head.

```
git diff HEAD~0
```

where 0 is the desired number of commits.

Comment: might want to use HEAD, in caps

Comment: thanks for the comment, I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If last versions means *last tag*, and current versions means HEAD (current state), it's just a diff with the last tag:

Looking for [tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging):

```
$ git tag --list
...
v20.11.23.4
v20.11.25.1
v20.11.25.2
v20.11.25.351
```

The last tag would be:

```
$ git tag --list | tail -n 1
v20.11.25.351
```

Putting it together:

```
tag=$(git tag --list | tail -n 1)
git diff $tag
```