# Inspecting between two commits in local repo

Tags: git, github, range, git-log

How can I display commits between two commits in the past in log of commits?
I found [this article useful.](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/05/git-tip-of-week-git-revisions.html)

But I cant understand the references/others.
Can somebody make it clear to me, please?

I found that if for example, I want to inspect between last 3rd and 4th commits this is the command 
`git log HEAD^2 -2`

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903541/finding-diff-between-current-and-last-versions

Comment: I just want to see the logs no diif, but thanks

Comment: You need to clarify your question. You write: *How can I display commits between two commits [...]* Did you mean "differences between two commits"?

Comment: @Jubobs: no only the logs

Comment: What is your question, then? Still unclear...

Comment: @Jubobs: I want to see the list of commit logs but in a ranges which is specified by me. Serban answered me bellow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`git log` takes a range of commits as an argument, so you could do `git log commit1..commit2`

Comment: A Simple question: How can is indicate `commit1` and `commit2`
without using this long strings 
commit 3e63c4d92b46b88a04073d3f524d12dc0ae0f2aa

Comment: @AliSaberi There are multiple ways of referring to commits other than by their full hashes, all explained in the following section of the Pro Git book: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection. Read it.