# Git diff all local uncommitted changes

Tags: git, git-diff

I have a following problem. I want to get the output from `git diff`, but for all uncommitted local changes (that means unstaged and staged files).

I am not searching for git log, or any other output, it has to be `git diff` output, because then I am parsing it with the parser I made.

For now I have:

All unstaged files:

```sh
git diff
```

Staged + unstaged files + all local commits (compare to remote)

```sh
git diff origin/master
```

Now I am missing the part when I can get `git diff` for all unstaged and staged files, but not compare it with remote (cuz it would take all local commits too), but just compare it with last local commit. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Doesn't quite fit your requirements, but [`git diff --cached`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgt--cachedltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203) will show you just the staged files - perhaps that combined with `git diff` will be enough to achieve your goal?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate question, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903541/finding-diff-between-current-and-last-version/9903570#9903570) might be helpful - it's suggesting `git diff HEAD` will show what you're looking for

Comment: You might actually need *two* `git diff`s. Try this as an experiment in a temporary clone: take some file, such as `README.md`, and modify it and `git add README.md`. Now modify it *again*. Run `git status`. How many times does `README.md` show up? How will one `git diff` ever tell you that you have two *different* changes to the one file named `README.md`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903541/finding-diff-between-current-and-last-version/9903570#9903570), to a similar (but I don't think duplicate) question, I think what you're looking for is:

```
git diff HEAD
```

This will show you all the differences between your current working directory (i.e. your staged and unstaged changes) and the HEAD commit.

Or - if you prefer to match the syntax in your question, this would do the same thing:

```
git diff master
```

(where `master` is your current branch).