# What is the Git equivalent of cvs checkout -p?

Tags: git

Git's diff is quite good, but I think my users would prefer to see differences in the tool of their choice.  How can I acquire an untracked copy of a file from the local repository that represents file in its pristine condition, prior to any user changes?

With CVS, I could acquire the base revision of the user's file and then issue a  `cvs checkout -r base.rev -p >/tmp/some-file` command.  How does one do something like that in Git?

Comment: `git difftool` lets users see changes in their preferred diff tool.

Comment: See also: ["How do I configure git to use a different tool for diffing ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412516/configuring-diff-tool-with-gitconfig)

Answer (score 1):

First, look up what the first committed version of a file was;

```
git log --follow --stat <filename>
```

Using `--follow` is necessary to catch renames. Using `--stat` will show you the original filename.

Remember the commit and original filename of the first commit. Then;

```
git checkout <commit> <original filename>
```

That will give you the first version that was checked in.