# git difftool on ubuntu only returns diff on terminal not with meld

Tags: git, git-diff, meld, git-difftool

1. I have meld installed on the ubuntu machine and I've been able to open files using meld.
2. I followed the answer on [Setting up and using Meld as your git difftool and mergetool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119866/setting-up-and-using-meld-as-your-git-difftool-and-mergetool) to setup gifftool to use meld.
3. the following is my git config:

   ```
   diff.tool=meld
   difftool.prompt=false
   difftool.meld.cmd=meld $LOCAL $REMOTE
   ```
4. When I try :
   `git difftool`
   I get the differences on the terminal similar to the output of a git diff.

I would really appreciate some help here! 
Do I need additional scripts? Why does it not work for me?

Comment: What is the location of your git.config?

Answer (score 0):

**Test 0**

Let's test if `meld` works

Can you run `meld` in the console?

```
tymatm@XXX:/mnt/c/git/sandbox$ meld
```

---

**Test 1**

Let's test if setting a tool works.

```
tymatm@XXX:/mnt/c/git/sandbox$ git config --global diff.tool meld
```

and then:

```
tymatm@XXX:/mnt/c/git/sandbox$ git difftool

Viewing (1/2): '1.txt'
Launch 'meld' [Y/n]:
```

### From [Configuring diff tool with .gitconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412516/configuring-diff-tool-with-gitconfig#20123093)

**Test 1.5**

*Added since test 1 was failing*

Let's try the local, not global, config

```
tymtam@XYZ:/mnt/c/git/sandbox$ git config diff.tool meld
tymtam@XYZ:/mnt/c/git/sandbox$ git config difftool.prompt true
tymtam@XYZ:/mnt/c/git/sandbox$ cat .git/config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[diff]
        tool = meld
[difftool]
        prompt = true
tymtam@XYZ:/mnt/c/git/sandbox$ git difftool

Viewing (1/2): '1.txt'
Launch 'meld' [Y/n]: n
```

---

**Test 2**

Let's tests if the `cmd=` part works.

```
vi ~/.gitconfig
```

Here I'm using a simple `echo` to verify that the configuration works - in the final setup the command would be `cmd = meld XXX`

[image]

```
tymtam@XXX:/mnt/c/git/sandbox$ git difftool

Viewing (1/2): '1.txt'
Launch 'meld' [Y/n]: y
/tmp/VuquIm_1.txt 1.txt

Viewing (2/2): '2.txt'
Launch 'meld' [Y/n]: y
/tmp/drAZtV_2.txt 2.txt
tymek@LAPTOP-B0OQU3LB:/mnt/c/git/sandbox$
```

---

**Test 3**

Subsitute `echo` in `~/.gitconfig` with `meld`

Comment: Test 0 - works! but Test 1 does not result in a meld prompt. I've deleted all diff related changes from my git config and used only the config mentioned in test 1 and it still doesnt help :(

Comment: Added test 1.5 with local settings