# gitconfig difftool setup not working in Visual Studio 19

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-difftool

Having the following diff tool settings:

```
[difftool "edp"]
    cmd = \"C:/Program Files/ExamDiff Pro/ExamDiff.exe\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" //nh
    prompt = false
    trustexistcode = true
```

in `.gitconfig` results in a working diff tool from the console
`git difftool` or by right clicking in VS Code in the pending changes window.

How ever running from Visual Studio 19's integrated pending change windows: it does not work. 
[image: Crash]

It seems that arguments are not properly quoted???:

```
[difftool "edp"]
   cmd = "\"powershell.exe\" \"echoArgs.ps1\" \"...Bla bla bla...\"
[diff]
    tool = edp
    guitool = edp
```

prints

```sh
Args 1: '...Bla'
Args 2: 'bla'
...
```

You can replace `powershell` with `C:/Program Files/Git/bin/bash.exe`, the same happens...
How can you fix this absolutely stupid freaking backslash/quotes escaping mess happening?

**Update**: VS 19 installes the following command:

```
[difftool "vsdiffmerge"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Professional\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\vsdiffmerge.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" //t
    keepBackup = false
```

Which is basically very similar to mine...??

Any insight is very appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to configure it from VS2019 itself?

Comment: Yes, tried, see update

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `cmd` to look like the following:

`cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\ExamDiff Pro\\ExamDiff.exe\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" //nh`

Answer (score -2):

Detailed instructions for Git integration with "ExamDiff Pro" https://www.prestosoft.com/edp_versioncontrol.asp#git

See also: [Configuring diff tool with .gitconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412516/configuring-diff-tool-with-gitconfig)

```
[diff]
    tool = edp
    guitool = edp
[difftool "edp"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\ExamDiff Pro\\ExamDiff.exe\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" -nh -dn1:\"Theirs\"
```

From the screen capture of ExamDiff's output, replace `//nh` with `-nh`. Note this is also mentioned in the integration instructions.

Comment: You are surprised that an unfinished answer (which did look like "Use this different tool" instead of an explained solution) gets downvotes? You keep an unfinished answer up instead of deleting it for peaceful editing? Both surprises me. But now that you are editing in order to explain the solution you provide (instead of e.g. only linking to it....), or better as soon as you are done with that, the two downvoters might notice and undo. If you are lucky.

Comment: Consider the action as saving a draft while continuing to develop a better answer? The first sentence answers the question very specifically without having to manually edit the configuration file.

Comment: Yes I considered that as what you did and commented that I consider it of questionable wisdom. You are experienced enough to know that voters on StackOverflow are many and impatient - because there are so so many "use this instead" answers out there which are really meant to stay that way. If you are quick you can make your draft, publish it and delete it immediatly for improvement editing. But you did not try that... And "detailed instruction see link" is a link-only flaggable non-answer, if you mean that by "first sentence answers the question".

Comment: I'm willing to remove my downvote if you actually fix your answer.

Comment: I am not going to repeat instructions from a vendor.