# Setting WinMerge as Git Diff Tool

Tags: git

I followed this [use Winmerge inside of Git to file diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881594/use-winmerge-inside-of-git-to-file-diff) but it seem does not work for me

Git Version

```
$ git --version
  git version 2.6.2.windows.1
```

Git Config --list

```
diff.tool=winmerge
merge.tool=winmerge
```

`Git diff` does not launch WinMerge but display the diff on the console like below

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/config.gradle b/config.gradle
index 39239eb..2ef8cb0 100644
--- a/config.gradle
+++ b/config.gradle
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-project.ext.productId = "kgxs"
+project.ext.productId = "kgxsll"
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: If winmerge.exe is not in your PATH, you'll need to specify the full path to it I believe.

Comment: If my understanding is correct here the *winmerge* refers to the script that is located in Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\mergetools which in turn finds the actual location of WinMerge

Comment: You're right, it checks PATH and variations of C:\Program Files - so if you used a different install path it might not find it.

Comment: My installation is in standard path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge" so I think that is not an issue

Comment: Try putting it in PATH anyway and see if that changes anything (even temporarily from the shell)

Comment: I did and it did not work

Comment: Try launching with `git difftool` instead.

Comment: ah ok. Yep that works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in a comment above, you should use `git difftool` to launch an external diff tool rather than `git diff` which will show the internal console diff.