# How to debug git difftool command ( WinMerge , git on windows)

Tags: git, winmerge, git-difftool

I have spend some time to configure git (git version 2.35.3.windows.1) to use WinMerge (2.16.20) as a external difftool. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881594/use-winmerge-inside-of-git-to-file-diff) was my entry point and this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/shawndumas/6158524) seem to help some people. Still no luck on my side.

```
$ git config --global --list
  ...
  diff.tool=winmerge
  difftool.winmerge.prompt=false
  difftool.winmerge.trustexitcode=true
  difftool.winmerge.cmd=.... (different versions see below)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Example
cmd = "/c/Program\\ Files\\ \\(x86\\)/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe" -u -e $LOCAL $REMOTE  
cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinMerge\\WinMergeU.exe\" -u -e \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

**Question 1:** In the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881594/use-winmerge-inside-of-git-to-file-diff) the author refers to version 2.5 of git. But the official repo list 2.36 as lastest release. There seems to be a 2.5 release from 2015 for windows. Is that experimental? Or not official?

**Question 2:** Can somebody explain to what `git difftool` is doing behing the scenes? Is there a way to simulate the call outside of git, so I could debug it better? Maybe someone also had this problem an could explain how he debugged the problem

I have no error message (seems to get swallowd ...)

Comment: Is your winmerge actually located in c:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge?

Comment: Tim, thanks yes it is. Running it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a nightmare to write correct spaces, slashes and backslashes of Windows paths in gitconfig. To avoid it, add `c:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge` to the system variable `Path` (google `windows how to edit system variables`)  so that we can invoke an executable (`WinMergeU.exe` in your case) under the paths directly in the command line instead of its absolute path.

After updating `Path`, reopen git-bash to reload it. Run `git config --global -e` to edit `difftool.winmerge.cmd`

```
[difftool "winmerge"]
    cmd = WinMergeU.exe -u -e "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

To test if it works, enter a git repository and run `git difftool HEAD^ HEAD`. You can try other `git diff` commands, replacing `git diff` with `git difftool`.

Comment: Wow, that I did not think about. Now that did the trick for me. You made my day. Thanks