# Git Push Questions - Pedantic

Tags: git

I have a master branch and a searchfeature branch in my project. I have pushed the searchfeature branch to the remote repository, all okay so far

When I was working on that branch this morning, I did "git push" I got the following:

```
warning: You did not specify any refspecs to push, and the current remote
warning: has not configured any push refspecs. The default action in this
warning: case is to push all matching refspecs, that is, all branches
warning: that exist both locally and remotely will be updated.  This may
warning: not necessarily be what you want to happen.
warning: 
warning: You can specify what action you want to take in this case, and
warning: avoid seeing this message again, by configuring 'push.default' to:
warning:   'nothing'  : Do not push anything
warning:   'matching' : Push all matching branches (default)
warning:   'tracking' : Push the current branch to whatever it is tracking
warning:   'current'  : Push the current branch
```

So I went ahead a did a git config push.default tracking and voila, git push works this no problem, no warning.

What I dont understand is what the difference between "current" and "tracking" is, if you don't do "to whatever it is tracking" then what is the point of "current" - where would it go?, what scenarios would you use current rather than tracking?

Also, what scenarios would one ever use "nothing"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since [Git1.6.3](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/RelNotes-1.6.3.txt):

> When the user does not tell "`git push`" what to push, it has always pushed matching refs.
>   For some people it is unexpected, and a new configuration variable `push.default` has been introduced to allow changing a different default behavior.
>   To advertise the new feature, a big warning is issued if this is not configured and a git push without arguments is attempted.

So the difference between current and tracking is that:

- current will assume a matching ref (a remote branch with the *same name*, which may not exist)
- tracking will based the remote ref to use on the tracking ref associated with that local branch. If it does not track anything, it won't push. But it can track a remote branch with a different name.a remo

Note: `default nothing` would be useful for read-only repository, made only for content consultation, where no work is supposed to be done and published anywhere.

See also the [git push current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/git-push-current-branch) SO question.

---

Update March 2012: **Beware: that default "matching" policy might change soon**:

See "[Please discuss: what "git push" should do when you do not say what to push?](http://git-blame.blogspot.fr/2012/03/please-discuss-what-git-push-should-do.html)"

> **In the current setting** (i.e. **`push.default=matching`**), **`git push` without argument will push all branches that exist locally and remotely with the same name**.
>   This is usually appropriate when a developer pushes to his own public repository, but may be confusing if not dangerous when using a shared repository.
>
> The proposal is to **change the default to '`upstream`'**, i.e. push only the current branch, and push it to the branch git pull would pull from.
>   Another candidate is '`current`'; this pushes only the current branch to the remote branch of the same name.
>
> What has been discussed so far can be seen in this thread:

http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/192547/focus=192694

> Previous relevant discussions include:

- http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/123350/focus=123541
- http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/166743

> To join the discussion, send your messages to: git@vger.kernel.org