# Why does checking out remote branches in git specifying a local branch name act differently to using the remote default name?

Tags: git

According to documentation at https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html:

```
git checkout <branch>

  If <branch> is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly
  one remote (call it <remote>) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to

    $ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

If I subsequently call, say, `git checkout project/phpunit/trunk` (from a single remote of *origin*), then performing `git remote show origin` gives me:

```
Local branches configured for 'git pull':
  master                merges with remote master
  project/phpunit/trunk merges with remote project/phpunit/trunk
Local refs configured for 'git push':
  master                pushes to master                (up to date)
  project/phpunit/trunk pushes to project/phpunit/trunk (up to date)
```

However, if I wanted to call my local branch something less wordy, and I instead used, based on what this the documentation suggests, `git checkout -b phpunit --track origin/project/phpunit/trunk` instead, a subsequent `git remote show origin` gives:

```
Local branches configured for 'git pull':
  master  merges with remote master
  phpunit merges with remote project/phpunit/trunk
Local ref configured for 'git push':
  master pushes to master (up to date)
```

In a nutshell, the tracking for pulling is intact, however, the creation of a reference for pushing is not.

It doesn't necessarily bother me that there is this difference in use, but I would like to know what I'm missing in my knowledge of git as to the **reason** for this disparity.

If there *is* a method of creating-and-checking-out a new local branch based on a remotely tracked branch, but naming it with a different local name: what is that method?

Many thanks for reading.

Comment: Looks like an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121378/git-tracking-doesnt-work-with-different-local-and-remote-names?rq=1

Comment: Excellent: thanks. No idea why my own searching on SO failed to find that.