# Why does git reject on master when pushing to different branch

Tags: git, git-flow

We're using git flow. Here is the flow.

1. git flow feature start myfeat
2. git commit -a
3. git checkout develop
4. git pull
5. git flow feature checkout myfeat
6. git flow feature rebase myfeat
7. git flow feature finish myfeat
8. git push

error:

```
Counting objects: 15, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 820 bytes, done.
Total 8 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:blah/blah.git
   d675b35..d35f160  develop -> develop
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

Why does it tell me that it's rejecting master when i'm pushing to develop (develop is a remote tracking branch if your not familiar with git flow)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, `git push` tries to update all upstream branches (those matching `branch.<name>.merge` in your configuration).

Try this:

```
git config push.default tracking
```

This tells git to only push commits to the upstream branch matching the name of the local branch you currently have checked out.

See also

- [the `git-config(1)` manpage](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-config.html)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/948397/156060

Comment: Awesome - was puzzled by this