# Github: Pushing to pull requests

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I'm about to pull my hair out.

I've submitted a pull request from my fork of a project, back to the owner/maintainer's repo.  In this pull request, some things came up that I had to add/change based on new information.  I've made said changes, and now I'm trying to PUSH to that pull request.

According to Github's "issue" page, at the bottom, it says I can push commits directly to the issue (pull request) by pushing to branch `abc123` on my fork of the repository.

The problem is, when i do `git push origin abc123` I get the error:

```
fatal: 5fa087b35cb8379f282174df2f4197ba258ffd05 cannot be resolved to branch.
```

I'm not sure how to fix this.  Should I just close the pull request and re-submit? Or is there something I'm doing wrong, or more than I need to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is actually (from [GitHub Remotes help page](http://help.github.com/remotes/#pushing))

```
git push REMOTENAME LOCALBRANCHNAME:REMOTEBRANCHNAME
```

You did not:

- create a local branch 'abc123'
- specify a local branch name

So, what should work is (if you are on master branch for instance):

```
git push origin master:abc123
```

Generally, the [default push policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/948397/6309) is "matching": `git push origin abc123` would try to push a local branch named `abc123` to a remote branch with the same name.

Comment: That worked, and clears things up.  I guess I'm just a gitnoob.  Mercurial doesn't have these crazy features (or...I never use them) haha.