# Git Flow : Do you have to manually delete the feature branches from remote after finishing the feature?

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-flow

I am new to `GIT` and `GIT-Flow`. [ On my python-django project ]

What I did :

```
git flow feature start new_feature
# perform some commits on the feature/new_feature branch

git push origin feature/new_feature

git flow feature finish new_feature
# I suppose that merges feature/new_feature to develop and deletes feature/new_feature

git push origin develop # Pushes the new changes to remote
```

Problem:

- The feature/new_feature branch seems to be deleted on my local machine.
- But on `github` [ My remote named origin ] I can see the branch feature/new_feature.
- I am confused, it shouldn't show deleted branches.
- I looked around for solution - but they say you should delete them on remote manually, which doesn't seem to fit the abstraction of `git flow`

So, do you guys have to delete all your feature branches from all the remotes every time you use `git-flow` ??

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: haven't you pushed in between? unless there's no way the branch appears on origin

Comment: I pushed after I finished the feature, I suppose it should also delete the remote branches if I delete it on my local git and pushed. 
Why is this out-of-sync in git repos even after a push ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you ever did a `git push origin` (with `feature` being checked out locally), know that the current default pushing policy is default.
That means ([`git config` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config.html))

> **`matching`** - push *all* branches having the same name in both ends.

But:

> This is currently the default, but **Git 2.0 will change the default to `simple`**.
>
> `upstream` - push the current branch to its upstream branch.
> With this, git push will update the same remote ref as the one which is merged by git pull, making push and pull symmetrical.

(since `feature` has initially no upstream branch in GitHub, it wouldn't be pushed)

(That change of policy is [in discussion for the past few months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/git-push-current-branch/9749535#9749535))

So for now, if you did push your `feature` branch to GitHub, before merging it locally to `develop` and pushing `develop`, you need to remove your feature branch from GitHub:

```
git push origin :feature
```

The only reason why [git flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/develop/git-flow-feature) wouldn't remove a feature branch if you didn't specified a flag '`fetch`' at any point during the process. [See sources](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/develop/git-flow-feature#L338-L355).

```
# delete branch
if flag fetch; then
  git push "$ORIGIN" ":refs/heads/$BRANCH"
fi
```

That means you should have done a

```
git flow feature finish -F new_feature
```

The idea is to fetch first and make sure there is no new evolution added to `new_feature` on GitHub by *other* contributors, before deleting it.

Comment: Sir, please see the edit to the question. I missed some info.

Comment: @YugalJindle I just added a reference to git flow source.

Comment: I understand that sir, but then why doesn't it deletes the branch on the remote origin when I push after the deletion of the branch locally. As per present `push` policy - It should. Shouldn't it ?

Comment: @YugalJindle your last push concerns only `develop`, not `new_feature`. If `new_feature` wasn't deleted on the remote by `git flow finish`, your push wouldn't change that.

Comment: @YugalJindle Isee in the source that the remote branch is only deleted if the flag 'fetch' has been defined. That happens only if you do a `git flow finish -F ...` (no `-F`, no fetch option, no remote deletion)

Comment: Is there a way so that I can reflect all local commits to remote, across branches?

Comment: @YugalJindle I just edited my answer. The deletion would have been reflected with the `-F` option to `git flow finish`. Right now, I would recommend a manual fix (the `git push :new_feature`).