# Github repo not showing latest commits

Tags: git, github, ssh, commit, git-commit

For some reason my Github repo is not showing the latest couple of commits. I did **git add, git commit, and git push** like I always do. But tonight it seemed to not have registered on the repo's commit history.

When I do a git log, I can see my latest commits. When I do a git pull into a new folder to test it, my changes are there. When I manually take the commit url and put it in my browser, I can see the changes. *It is just not showing up on the commit history and the overall number of commits on the project is not updating*. Why is this?

Comment: on github, check Graphs -> Network, on the graphic git log can you see the last couple of commits?

Comment: If you try `git push` again, does it say it's already up to date? Is this on the main (master) branch? Is this a public repo which you can share a link to, and the commit id of a missing commit?

Comment: @armnotstrong on Graph -> Network, it just says Loading Graph Data and a spinning progress sign. Does not show actual data

Comment: @Patrick yep, when I git push again, it says already up to date, and sorry it's a private repo unfortunately

Comment: @jebmarcus : Same thing happened with me many times on `Bitbucket`. Just try `push` a new `commit` and everything will be updated.

Comment: @Shravan40 I tried a new commit, basically changed one line and pushed, but same thing, no commits are showing

Comment: @jebmarcus : Are you working in `master` ?

Comment: this is confusing to me. I used to be able to push with `git push` without having to specify the origin (or the branch). But now I can't push without doing `git push -u origin master`. My removes look fine `originn git@github.com:brando90/ultimate-utils.git (push)` after going `git remote -v`...what happened to my git configuration than now I have to explicitly specify where I am pushing and git push by itself is not longer working? btw this looks related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173971/commits-not-showing-up-on-github

Comment: also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173971/commits-not-showing-up-on-github

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check first your status and branches:

```
git status
git branch
```

If you don't see a branch preceded with a `*`, that means you are working in a [detached HEAD branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309).

If that is the case, simply reset your master branch to your current HEAD and push again:

```
git checkout -B master @
git push
```

---

The [OP jebmarcus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5966599/jebmarcus) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734255/github-repo-not-showing-latest-commits/38736387#comment64864280_38736387) to be on the master branch though, and with a clean status:

> When I refreshed the repo this morning everything is working again

That must have been a glitch on GitHub side.
There were connection issues on GitHub (there was a "Minor service outage" on August 3rd -- [GitHub status messages](https://status.github.com/messages)).

Comment: Thanks but when I do git branch I do see * master

Comment: When I refreshed the repo this morning everything is working again

Comment: git status said: On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: So yes, a refresh issue on Github side, then

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: I will accept this answer as it might help other people in their cases

Comment: @jebmarcus OK, I have updated the answer with your conclusion as well, for more visibility.

Comment: I am confused also also see `* master`...what is going on?

Comment: this is confusing to me. I used to be able to push with `git push` without having to specify the origin (or the branch). But now I can't push without doing `git push -u origin master`. My removes look fine `originn git@github.com:brando90/ultimate-utils.git (push)` after going `git remote -v`...what happened to my git configuration than now I have to explicitly specify where I am pushing and git push by itself is not longer working?

Comment: @CharlieParker Could you ask that in a separate question, with your OS, OS version, git version, and output of `git branch -avv`?

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me a similar issue where github did not show latest commits on web.
Apparently everything was up to date in my github remote repo, but I just had to re-enter my credentials with git push, in order to see the changes in browser.

First make sure your git user and remote repo are correct:

```
[repo-dir]$ git config user.email
your-user@email

[repo-dir]$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/your-user-name/your-repo (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/your-user-name/your-repo (push)
```

Then pull and push again:

```
[repo-dir]$ git pull origin master
From https://github.com/your-user-name/your-repo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.

[repo-dir]$ git push

Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/manosnoam/ansible-tempest-remote
   da33d75..ae56129  master -> master
```

A message has prompted me to enter my git username/password.

Right after that, I saw my commit changes in github web.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I was new to git and trying random stuff but my repo was not taking recent changes even if I do `git reset --hard` , then I tried this.

`git pull`