# How do I squelch "fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match the name of your current branch"?

Tags: git

There is a related question on SO dealing with how to change the parameters of the `push` command to avoid this message:

[fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match the name of your current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24864700/fatal-the-upstream-branch-of-your-current-branch-does-not-match-the-name-of-you)

I'm interested in how to squelch the message itself, *without* changing the names of my local/remote branches or using fancy `push` commands.

Suppose I have a local branch tracking a remote branch of a different name:

```
user@home:~ git branch -vv
branch-name abcd1234 [remote/origin/branch-name] last commit message
```

Now I want to be able to push my commited changes by simply typing `git push`. When I do this, I get the following message:

> ```
> fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
> the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
> on the remote, use
>
>     git push origin HEAD:remote/origin/branch-name
>
> To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use
>
>     git push origin branch-name
> ```

How do I force `git` to automatically push to the upstream branch even if the names don't match? I'm using `git 1.9.1`

Answer (score 9):

Newer Git (v 1.9 or newer)

```
git config --global push.default upstream
```

Older Git

```
git config --global push.default tracking
```

Git 2.3 still accepts `tracking` as a synonym for upstream

Just do that once and whenever you "git push" it will push your current branch to its configured upstream.

This also sets it in your global config, which might be shadowed by a different setting in your repository config.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I entered that command and then typed `git push` and got the same message.

Comment: see if there is a conflicting setting in the repository .git/config file, or in the system /etc/gitconfig

Comment: `tracking` seems suspect-at-best: the 5 listed possible values are `current`, `matching`, `nothing`, `simple`, and `upstream`.  In this case `upstream` seems the most likely desired one.

Comment: tracking and upstream are the same, I mentioned that in my answer.  Git changed the name sometime between 1.7 and 2.0, I don't know when specifically.  tracking will still work as of 2.1, but if you configure upstream and ever try to use 1.7 or older it definitely won't work.

Comment: Thank you, hard to believe this is not default behavior. I track this remote branch for a reason..