# Does a Git a push configuration allow specifying the branch as well?

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull, git-refspec

I have a branch which pulls from one remote and pushes to another and U used `git branch --set-upstream-to=xxxx xxxx` to set the pull repo and `git config remote.origin.pushurl user@user.com:repo.git` to set the push repo.

Although the pull is from the `master` branch on the source repo, the `push` goes to the `upstream` branch on the destination repo.

When I switch to the branch and I do a `git push` I get the usual `--global push.default` message:

```
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value has changed in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the traditional behavior, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.
```

Is there a way to specify for a particular branch which branch of the remote it should push to, rather than the `push.default` value, and similarly for pulls as well?

Comment: do you mean to push to a same name branch in a different repository?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25964577/how-do-i-squelch-fatal-the-upstream-branch-of-your-current-branch-does-not-mat/

Comment: @AndrewC No. the idea is to push to any arbitrarily named branch that is different from the branch name

Comment: Isn't that what the answer covered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the idea is to push to any arbitrarily named branch that is different from the branch name

Simply specify an [upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309):

```
git branch --set-upstream-to my_local_branch origin/my_remote_branch
```

Then subsequent pushes will know to which branch to push `my_local_branch`.

You would still need to setup a push policy (`git config push.default simple`)

To push to one repo, but pull from another, you can setup the pushurl to be different from the pull/fetch url

```
git config remote.origin.pushurl /url/for/origin/repo
git config remote.origin.url /url/for/upstream/repo
```

That would allow to manage everything with "one" remote (which actually references two different repos)

You can also update the refspecs for the upstream branch part:

```
git config remote.origin.push refs/heads/my_local_branch:refs/heads/my_remote_branch
git config remote.origin.fetch refs/heads/my_local_branch:refs/heads/my_local_branch
```

Comment: I haven't really played with this yet, just reading the manpages. You still have to provide the local branch name for either `matching` or `simple`, don't you (meaning a ref-less `git push` will not suffice)?

Comment: The repo that is pulled from is not the same repo that is pushed to. `--set-upstream-to` specifies the branch pulled from, and the branch names are different. The pull is from `master` on the source repo, but `upstream` on the destination repo. The `upstream` repo is never pushed to.
I wanted to edit the comment but it timed out

Comment: Your latest answer with the `remote.origin.pushurl` setting is what  I was inquiring about. Does that configuration syntax allow one to specify the branch as well, ie `git config remote.origin.pushurl /url/for/origin/repo/<branch>`, in order for `git push` to work even if the `--global push.default` has not been set?

Comment: @vfclists the branch is set by the push refspec, not the push url. See http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#REMOTES, and http://longair.net/blog/2011/02/27/an-asymmetry-between-git-pull-and-git-push/:  “refspecs” are usually of the form `<src>:<dst>`, telling you which local branch (src) you’d like to update the remote branch (def) with.  However, the default behaviour if you don’t add `:<dst>`, as in this example, is explained as If `:<dst>` is omitted, the same ref as `<src>` will be updated.

Comment: In my instance the branch pulls from master branch in the source repo and pushes to the upstream branch in the destination. Would that result in some like this:


`    [remote "upstream"]`
`        url = https://github.com/sourceuser/repo.git`
`        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*`
`        tagopt = --tags`
`        pushurl = https://github.com/destuser/repo.git`
`        push = +refs/heads/upstream:refs/remotes/upstream`

Comment: @vfclists yes, my idea was to associate those different urls to "`origin`" in order to have a default `git fetch` or `git push` to do the right thing.

Comment: Can you update the answer with the refspec example? I thought the issue could be resolved from the command line, but in this case it appears to require editing of `.git/config`

Comment: @vfclists I have updated the answer (not tested) with a git config similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/1915046/6309