# Failed push with bare Git repo

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote, git-bare

I have a remote bare repo `master` and a local branch `cloud` which I have set to track it with

```
git branch cloud -u amazon/master
```

but

```
git push
```

results in

> fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
>   the name of your current branch.

I've tried the solution suggested in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24864700/656912) (which is, as near as I can tell, what I've done above), but it get the same error.

How I get configure tracking so that `git push` alone will push to the remote?

---

The relevant parts of my `config`:

```
[remote "amazon"]
        url = ssh://ubuntu@ecXXXXXXXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/home/ubuntu/mlcode.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/amazon/*
[branch "cloud"]
        remote = amazon
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: try `git config push.default upstream` before `git push`

Comment: @ElpieKay: Can you say a bit more about how that works here?

Comment: You could read about `push.default` in `git config --help`

Comment: @ElpieKay: I din't see anything there about "how that works here".

Comment: when the branch names don't match (your branch vs the branch in the remote repository) use the 'git push  REPO MYBRANCH:THEIRBRANCH' form of the command.

Comment: By default, `git push` the local branch to a remote branch which has the same name. Your local name is `cloud`, which differs from the remote name `master`, therefore the push fails. If `push.default` is set to `upstream`, `git push` pushes the local branch to its upstream instead of the remote branch with the same name. However an explicit command like `git push amanzon cloud:master` is the safest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running

```
git config push.default upstream
```

will give you the desired behavior.

According to the [`git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), the default behavior in version 2.0 is

> - `simple` - in centralized workflow, work like upstream with an added safety to refuse to push if the upstream branch’s name is different from the local one.
>
>   When pushing to a remote that is different from the remote you normally pull from, work as current. This is the safest option and is suited for beginners.

In contrast, the `upstream` mode operates as follows.

> - `upstream` - push the current branch back to the branch whose changes are usually integrated into the current branch (which is called `@{upstream}`). This mode only makes sense if you are pushing to the same repository you would normally pull from (*i.e.*, central workflow).

Working with a repository similar to yours

```
$ git branch
* cloud
  master
```

and nothing up my sleeve

```
$ git config --unset push.default
```

attempting to push gives the same error. Verbose mode (`-v`) is there so you can see what git is doing.

```
$ git push -v
fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use

    git push amazon HEAD:master

To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use

    git push amazon cloud

To choose either option permanently, see push.default in 'git help config'.
```

After a config change

```
$ git config push.default upstream
```

you get the behavior described in your question.

```
$ git push -v
Pushing to .../amazon/
To .../amazon/
 = [up to date]      cloud -> master
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/amazon/master'
Everything up-to-date
```