# Merge two different remote branches in command line

Tags: git, merge, git-remote

I have 2 diffrent remotes

1. origin1: "https://github.com/xxx.."
2. origin2: "https://github.com/yyy.."

Each origin have a branch with same name. (branch_xxx)

How can i merge "origin1/branch_xxx" changes to "origin2/branch_xxx" using command line

Comment: won't `git check out origin1/branch_xxx; git merge origin2/branch_xxx` do?

Comment: It works but after that when i  try to push merge with "git push origin1/branch_xxx" i am getting following error "fatal: You are not currently on a branch." @Lei Yang

Comment: Yes, because attempting to directly checkout a remote-tracking branch is akin to checking out a commit, and results in a detached HEAD state. To reattach HEAD, create a new branch where your detached HEAD is, with `git branch <name_for_the_new_branch>` or just checkout an existing branch.

Answer (score 1):

You can't work directly on `origin2/branch_xxx` which is not a local branch but a mere image of the last position of `branch_xxx` last time you fetched from `origin2` (what's called a *remote-tracking branch*).

What you *can* do is work on a local copy (3 steps) :

**1)** Create a local copy of origin2/branch_xxx which will receive the merge

```
git checkout -b branch_xxx origin2/branch_xxx
```

**2)** Then merge origin1/branch_xxx into it (for the source branch no need for a copy)

```
git merge origin1/branch_xxx
```

(and deal with potential conflicts as usual)

**3)** Finally, push the result to origin2

```
git push origin2 branch_xxx
```

---

Note : to have a better understanding of what are these remote-tracking refs and how to work with them, take a look at [this excellent summation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) in the official doc.

Answer (score 0):

###### 1. Make sure you have added the remote

Check your remotes with `git remote -v`. If a remote is missing, add with `git add remotename`.

###### 2. Fetch

You need to have the tip or latest commit of both branches in your local machine. Run: `git fetch --all`. Or, `git fetch origin1 branch_xxx` and `git fetch origin2 branch_xxx`.

###### 3. Make sure you have the local branch that tracks the remote branch you want to merge to

Checkout to the remote branch you want to merge to: `git checkout origin2/branch_xxx`. Note: now you're in a `detached HEAD` state (you're not in a branch). Eventhough you checked out to a remote branch, you're still in your local machine.

Now create a branch that will track the remote branch: `git checkout -b origin2-branch_xxx` and set it to track the remote: `git branch --set-upstream-to origin2/branch_xxx`. To check if a local branch has already tracked a remote branch, run `git branch -vv`.

###### 4. Merge

Now you're in `origin2-branch_xxx` which tracks `origin2/main`, merge `origin1/main` with `git merge origin1/main`. Then push the merge to `origin2` with `git push`:

```
fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use

    git push origin2 HEAD:branch_xxx

To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use

    git push origin2 HEAD

To choose either option permanently, see push.default in 'git help config'.
```

Oops.. [for safety reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42642628/9157799), you can't push directly if the local and the remote branch have different name. So, run `git push origin2 HEAD:branch_xxx` instead.

Comment: By the way, for the case where you want to merge a one-time merge (common in open source),  and the repo is big, you might want to use [shallow fetch/clone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6941889/9157799) with [--depth option](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---depthltdepthgt).