# Understanding git push command

Tags: git, git-push

I am trying to understand one git command.

In my local repository, I'm currently on `master`.

I'm on a remote called `origin`, in which two branches live: `master` and `review`.
However, I have another remote that is also called `review`...

My question is this: what happens when I run the following command?

```
git push review
```

Does it pushes changes to `review` branch on the same remote?
Or does it pushes changes to another remote with the name `review`?

Comment: What you mean by *I'm on Origin remote* is unclear. Your local repository may list other repositories as its "remotes", but "being on a remote" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand how this can be confusing. You would do well to choose distinct names for your branches and remotes.

When running `git push review`, you're essentially using the following syntax

```
git push <repository> [<refspec>...]
```

but you're leaving the optional `<refspec>...` argument out. Therefore, here, `git push` understands `review` as a remote, not as a branch. So `git push review` will be pushing changes (if not *everything is up-to-date*) to your remote called `review`.

How will those changes get pushed? Here is a relevant passage of the `git-push` man page:

```
When the command line does not specify what to push with
<refspec>... arguments or --all, --mirror, --tags options, the
command finds the default <refspec> by consulting remote.*.push
configuration, and if it is not found, honors push.default
configuration to decide what to push (See gitlink:git-config[1] for
the meaning of push.default).
```

So what happens when you run `git push review` depends on your Git configuration. Run

```
git config remote.review.push
```

If a match is found, then the corresponding value dictates what happens when you run `git push review`. If no match is found, Git uses the value of `push.default` to figure out what to do; run

```
git config push.default
```

to see which mode `push.default` is currently in. For more details on what `push.default` does, I refer you to [Default behavior of "git push" without a branch specified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/948354/2541573)

Answer (score 0):

You can look to the documentation.

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

```
[<repository> [<refspec>...]]
```

First `repository` and then the branch. But if you don't specify the branch name he takes the same name of the branch you actually checked out.