# How to push only current branch from local to remote repo in git?

Tags: git, git-branch

My local repo has 2 branches: `master` and `doing`, I only create commits in `doing` branch and when I finish the project, I merge it to `master` branch. When I checkout `master` branch and push to the remote repo, 2 branches are pushed to the remote. How can I push only `master` branch to remote repo in order that, commits in `doing` branch are not appear on remote repo?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default behavior of "git push" without a branch specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/default-behavior-of-git-push-without-a-branch-specified)

Answer (score 3):

You can manually specify which branch to push:

```
git push origin master
```

Or you can [configure git](https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/docs/git-config) to always only push the current branch:

```
git config --global push.default simple
```

Comment: I tried it but when I see the graph of the remote repo, still it has many commits in `doing` branch in order that the `doing` branch is not appear in the graph. Can I force many commits in `doing` branch not to push to remote repo? @andrew-c

Comment: If you've already pushed them, they will continue to appear. This will simply keep git from pushing those branches in the future.