# Git branches trying to push to master.

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push

I don't know what I changed, but recently when I try to push up one of my branches by using "git push" it tries to push to the remote branch and to master.

```
➜  module1 git:(my-branch) git push 
Counting objects: 40, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (25/25), done.
Writing objects: 100% (40/40), 3.68 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 40 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.corp.company.com:Project-1/SomeProject.git
   1000000..000000e  my-branch -> my-branch
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

Luckily each time it has happened I have gotten a rejected message because my branch has been behind master. I used to be able to just type git push, and it would only push the branch I was tracking. I have looked into my git config and it doesn't look like it should be pushing to master.

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.corp.company.com:Project-1/SomeProject.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "my-branch"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/my-branch
```

Any way I can prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Configure `push.default`

You want to set `push.default` to one of `simple`, `upstream`, or `current`.  In fact, you probably want `simple`.

To set `simple` mode for yourself, for all repositories where you have not set some other value, use:

```
git config --global push.default simple
```

To override this in one specific repository, use, e.g.:

```
git config push.default upstream
```

(assuming you want `upstream` mode for the current repository, regardless of your `--global` setting).

#### The "default default" depends on your version of Git.

In Git versions before 2.0, the initial default is `matching`.  This is the behavior you are seeing now and is clearly not what you want.

In Git versions 2.0 or later, the initial default is `simple`.  If this is what you want *and* `git --version` tells you that you have 2.0 or later, you don't have to set anything.

#### What `simple` and `upstream` mean

In Git, each of your branches (your local branch names, like `master` and `my-branch`) can have one "upstream" setting.  (Or it can have no upstream setting, but that's not very useful to us!)  The main command to set or change the upstream is `git branch --set-upstream-to`.

The upstream is itself essential two parts: the name of a remote, like `origin`, and the name of a branch on that remote, like `master`.  With `git branch --set-upstream-to` you just name the remote-tracking branch, `origin/master`, to set both at once, and it does the obvious thing.

Once set, `git push` will pick the remote from the name-of-the-remote part, and the branch to push *to* from the name-of-the-branch part.  (The branch you are pushing *from* defaults to your current branch, of course, and it's this current branch's upstream that sets the other two parts.)

Let's say that your current branch is `$branch` and that its upstream is `$remote/$upstream_branch`.  Using `simple` or `upstream` means that:

```
git push
```

means:

```
git push $remote $branch:$upstream_branch
```

The `simple` setting adds one extra constraint: this default push will *stop* (refuse to run) if `$upstream_branch` is not the *same* name as `$branch`.

#### What `current` means

Note that both of the above require that the *current* branch *have an upstream*.  Using `current` is sort of like using `simple`, except that Git doesn't require a full upstream setting.  It only needs the "remote" part.  (You can write `git push origin` to supply that part, or your current branch can have a remote set, with or without the other half of the upstream.)  Instead of needing `$upstream_branch`, `git push` now just does:

```
git push $remote $branch:$branch
```

Again, the new default is `simple` and that's usually the right setting.

Answer (score 0):

I would be careful in using `git push` without specifying the repository and refspec arguments. According to the [git-push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) documentation, git will default to the `branch.*.remote` repo and the `remote.*.push` refspec.

In personal practice I always push with something like the following...

`git push origin my-branch`

You can always use `git branch -vv` to display what remote each branch is tracking. Would be helpful for further debugging.

Edit: Here is a [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/948397/6561082) that looks to be a great explanation on the default behavior of `git push`