# GIT: Synchronize local files to new github repository

Tags: git, github

I frequently want to do this, but can never remember how.

First I create a file on my computer, some source code, and now I want to push it to a github repo.

So I create a github repo. (On github) Click "clone" to get the URL for later.

Now I run the following commands on my local machine.

```
git init // make a repo, local
git add * // add files to repo
git commit -a -m "initial commit" // commit files to repo and add msg
git remote add origin (...url...) // tell git where to push
git push --set-upstream origin master // no idea what this does
git config --global user.name "...name..." // set my name so github knows what my username is
git push // does not work error:

To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Still can't "push". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default behavior of "git push" without a branch specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/default-behavior-of-git-push-without-a-branch-specified)

Comment: Is the code block in your question a log of the commands you actually ran? Because if you try running `git push --set-upstream origin master` after you have run the `git remote add origin <url>` command, it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try cloning, then `cd` into the repo. After, `add *`. Then run your desired commit and push. This should work. If i were to do this without making any branches, it would look like this:

```
> git clone 'repoName'
> cd repoName 
> git add *
> git commit -m "first commit"
> git push
```

Comment: I thought a git clone would wipe my local files?

Comment: clone the repo, then move the code from your computer into that repo. Also, always remember to save a backup!