# shortcut for git to push to this branch that I am already on?

Tags: git

I have been using `git push origin branch-name` for a while even for the fact that I am already on the `branch-name` branch (check with `git branch`).

So I wonder is there something like `git push origin this` sorta command so that I can push change into my branch that I am already on, without have to do the two step process of `git branch` and then the copy and paste of branch name every time?

Been doing this for a year and silly enough I think its time for a better way to do this to save my time.
Thanks!

Comment: i think simply doing `git push` works. edit: Your remote must be set and current branch must be tracked to remote branch.. which i think happens automatically..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default behavior of "git push" without a branch specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/default-behavior-of-git-push-without-a-branch-specified)

Comment: @Vasif hum.... I did once with `git push origin` and it did not work, trying `git push` did not come to my mind at that time lol I am going to try it tomorrow! thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think time has come for you to become more hackish to dominate the command line and guess what...its the [`ZSH` shell](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) that will enable you to type

```
ggpush
```

which will be converted to:

```
git push origin <current-branch>
```

and similarly `ggpull` will result in `git pull origin <current-branch>`

Easy, isn't it?!

You just need to enable the `git` plugin in `.zshrc` like:

```
plugins=(git)
```

to hack into this.

You will find the complete list of `git` shortcuts on the [wiki](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Plugin:git) or locally in

```
~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh
```

The complete [plugins](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Plugins) list will help you unleash the full power of this shell of huge popularity (**58k+** github stars!)

Answer (score 1):

You can configure git to push to the current branch by running this command...

```
git config --global push.default current
```

Then you only need to include a branch name when you want to push to a different branch.

Comment: Wow! Wonder why git does not make it to be default! that makes so much sense. Will try it for sure! Thanks

Comment: @Ezeewei Git is flexible. In `git push <remote> <commit-ish>:<remote_ref>`, `remote`, `commit-ish` or `remote_ref` can be omitted partially or fully according to the configuration. Git allows users to define the default behaviour.