# Push new local branch to origin without specifying new branch name

Tags: git

I cloned a remote branch to my local, and checked out to a new branch with the command:

```
git checkout -b branchname
```

and then I tried to push this new branch to remote and to setup upstream, but I incorrectly forgot to specify the branchname:

```
git push -u origin
```

what happens in this case? Did I cover other people's work on the remote branches?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the output? I'm pretty sure Git won't let you overwrite remote branches without forcing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default behavior of "git push" without a branch specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/default-behavior-of-git-push-without-a-branch-specified)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+default

Answer (score 0):

By default, `git checkout -b` does *not* set up a tracking branch,

so `git push -u origin` will fail and do nothing:

```
$ git push -u origin
fatal: The current branch cast has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin branchname

To have this happen automatically for branches without a tracking
upstream, see 'push.autoSetupRemote' in 'git help config'.
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to push **new** local branch to origin without specifying new branch name exclusively.

```
 git push origin $(git branch --show-current)
```

**Explanation :**

`git branch --show-current` shows the current branch name as string.

`git push origin` takes this newly created current branch name as branch name argument and pushes the current committed changes

For behavior of

```
git push -u origin
```

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/default-behavior-of-git-push-without-a-branch-specified) as mentioned in the commment.