# Can we set up a branch's upstreams in different remote repositories

Tags: git

In the config file, a branch is set up to have an upstream in a remote repository

```
[branch "mybranch"]
    remote = myremote
    merge = refs/heads/mybranch
```

Can we set up an upstream in a third remote repository, so that when the current branch is `mybranch`, `git push <remote>` will work without `refspec` specified for the branches? For example, will the following work?

```
[branch "mybranch"]
    remote = myremote
    merge = refs/heads/mybranch

[branch "mybranch"]
    remote = yourremote
    merge = refs/heads/mybranch
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default behavior of "git push" without a branch specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/default-behavior-of-git-push-without-a-branch-specified)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-push%5D+without+branch

Comment: What do you mean by *set up an upstream **in a second remote repository**?* The branch named `mybranch` can only have one remote, but each repository has its own set of branches, so the only way I can make sense of this is that you're asking: *If I make a different clone, that has a different set of branches, can I set an upstream for one of those branches?* and of course the answer to that is obvious.

Comment: Thanks. Updated @torek

Answer (score 1):

> For example, will the following work?
>
> ```
> [branch "mybranch"]
>     remote = myremote
>     merge = refs/heads/mybranch
>
> [branch "mybranch"]
>     remote = yourremote
>     merge = refs/heads/mybranch
> ```

No.  Git configuration files *are* flexible enough to support this, though there's no need for a second section.  That is, you can write this more simply as:

```
[branch "mybranch"]
    remote = myremote
    remote = yourremote
    merge = refs/heads/mybranch
```

but only a few parts of Git make any use of multiple settings.<sup>1</sup>  The `git push` command in particular decides whether you've specified a remote, and if you have not, it gets the *last* setting for `branch.branch.remote` (where *`branch`* is the current branch).  Then it decides whether you've specified a refspec, and if not, uses your `push.default` setting to decide how to ask the other Git to update one of its names based on your *`branch`*'s current commit.  So:

- if you specify a *`remote`* argument, the two remote settings are irrelevant;
- if not, Git takes the *last* one.

This means that all settings except for the last become irrelevant.

(There are ways to use triangular workflows, where you fetch from one repository but push to another, but this is not one.  Use [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=git+triangular+workflow) to find some.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The `git fetch` command is one that *does* make use of multiple settings: it takes all of the `fetch = ...` settings for any given remote, when it is doing a defaulted `git fetch`.  That is:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
    fetch = +refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/origin/develop
```

produces a repository that acts a lot like like a single-branch clone, except that it's what we might call a two-branch clone.