# rebase push will go to branch A or branch B

Tags: javascript, git, github, gitlab, rebase

**update1:**

right now I am facing conflicts when I do rebase. after I modify the code. Can you let me know what command to execute to remove the conflicts.
Providing the status below

```or-tag-here
sports/code/file (branchB)
$ git pull --rebase origin branchA
From https://gitlab.sports.com
 * branch            branchA -> FETCH_HEAD
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: wip html fixes
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       sports/ajax.js
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging sports/ajax.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in sports/ajax.js
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 wip html fixes
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".



sports/code/file (branchB|REBASE 1/2)
$ git status
rebase in progress; onto 89898989892323
You are currently rebasing branch 'branchB' on '89898989892323'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   sports/ajax.js

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

- I am trying to learn rebase.
- I have a branch A which is created from develop branch,
- from the branch A I created a new local branch B.
- i did a git rebase using this command `git pull --rebase origin A`
- no if I do `git push -f origin B` will my code go into branch B alone or will it go into branch A also.
- if I type git status in branch B I am seeing the below message.
- i followed this medium link  https://medium.com/@gitaumoses4/git-rebase-a-tool-for-excellent-git-workflow-3aaa1bba40a4
- can you tell me how to fix it, so that in future I can do it myself

```or-tag-here
$ git status
On branch B
Your branch and 'origin/B' have diverged,
and have 7 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: @dota2pro hey can you tell me this will push to which branch?

Comment: Use a ui git tool that will help you better , I use intellij idea it has a VCS tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From the branch A I created a new local branch B.

```
a--a--a (A)
       \
        b (B, origin/B, meaning this is the initial commit pushed to the remote repo)
```

> Now, if I do `git push -f origin B`, will my code go into branch `B` alone or will it go into branch `A` also.

Branch B alone, but that branch B will include branch A commit.

That is because, when  you did:

```
git checkout B
git pull --rebase origin A
```

You went from

```
a--a--a--a--a--a (A)
       \
        b--B--B--B--B--B (local work B)
        ^
    (origin/B)
```

To:

```
              (A)
               v
a--a--a--a--a--a--b'--B'--B'--B'--B'--B' (new rebased B work, on top of A)
       \
        b
    (still origin/B)
```

That is why you see:

> ```
> Your branch and 'origin/B' have diverged,
> and have 7 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
> ```

In your case, if `git status` shows you that you are working with B, you can do

```
git push --force
```

You will then get:

```
a--a--a--a--a--a--b'--B'--B'--B'--B'--B' (B, origin/B)
```

Your branch B now includes commits from A, but branch A remains unchanged.

Comment: hey I have one more question, instead of `git push -f origin` why are you doing `git push --force`, in my command why they are mentioning origin. I thought origin means initial branch and it will got branch A :(

Comment: @zizi "origin" doe snot mean "initial branch": it only means *where* to push (the URL of the remote repo). It is the default one used, so `git push --force` is the same as `git push -f origin`

Comment: @zizi If you have checked out branch B before forcing the push, *what* is push will be branch B only, because of the default push policy (https://stackoverflow.com/a/948397/6309)

Comment: hey I did seven different commits in my branch B, is it possible to combine all my commits into one since I have done rebase will It be problem, can you tell me how to achieve it

Comment: @zizi After a rebase, you still can squash your last n commits together: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5201642/6309

Comment: hey do I need to excute this two commands `git reset --soft HEAD~3 &&
git commit - m 'combine all `

Comment: @zizi Yes, but only after the rebase, and only if the last 3 commits are the one you want to squash into one.

Comment: thanks, can you help me with this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56226829/how-do-i-change-the-layout-for-smaller-screens-in-material-ui

Comment: @zizi Sure, I have posted my answer.

Comment: hey after executing this commands `git reset --soft HEAD~3 && git commit - m 'combine all` is it possible to merge code from branch B to branch A using git commands

Comment: @zizi Yes, with `git checkout A` and `git merge B`

Comment: @zizi To *merge* code from branch A to branch B? That is what [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) is made for. Do you have any issue with it?

Comment: @zizi That would be different, and would replay commits from A on top of B: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing In your case, this is not recommended.

Comment: hey now I am facing conflicts, can you help me in fixing the conflicts :(

Comment: @zizi Could you make that new updated case as a separate and new question? My answer was in the context of your original question.

Comment: hey can you help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56297314/rebase-conflict-issue-in-branch-b