# How to configure 'git diff' to use emacs diff

Tags: git, emacs

Is it possible to configure git diff to use emacs diff?
If yes, can you please tell me how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See this question: [how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-visual-diff-program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-visual-diff-program) for information on **git difftool**.

You can also use git from within emacs:  [EmacsWiki:  Git](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Git).

Comment: The question linked here goes through a nice explanation of arguments passed to the external differ, which I left up to the man pages in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be possible, according to the [Pro Git](http://progit.org) book.

See [chapter 7.1](http://progit.org/book/ch7-1.html#external_merge_and_diff_tools) for more information, but the quick'n'dirty of it seems to be

```
$ git config --global diff.external [your favorite differ here]
```

or, if you want it to your `~/.gitconfig`

```
[diff]
  external = [your favorite differ here]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are working within Emacs, you could [advice](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Defining-Advice.html) `vc-git-diff` (the function is found in [vc-git.el](http://www.koders.com/lisp/fidEDFF5F9554B56F6BD42DB7503641742E78E6A3AB.aspx?s=sort) for reference), to give you the option of using either git-diff or emacs-diff according to your whim (and it wouldn't require you "forking" the git library that comes bundled with Emacs).

Comment: `advice` link is dead

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean git-diff, not git-difftool, you are probably looking for the `diff.external` config option. You'll want to look at the git Diffs section of [git(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/). This section doesn't mention the config setting, though it's listed in [git-config(1)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use use

```
M-x term
```

Which will bring up a terminal inside of emacs which supports the page.

You can also do

```
$ git diff <your file> | cat
```

You can also open up the file and do M-x vc-diff.

Comment: This isn't really answering his question.