# GIT newbie: how to check what has been changed in my case?

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I am a newbie in GIT. I am developing project on a Ubuntu machine.

In my project root path, when type `git status` , I got the following output on terminal window:

```
# On branch develop
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   Rakefile
#   modified:   db/schema.rb
```

But, I do not know what has been changed/modified on those files, how to check what are the changes has been made on the two files?

Answer (score 8):

Just run:

```
 git diff
```

If you want nice coloured output from such commands, it's worth setting the config option `color.ui`, as in:

```
git config --global color.ui auto
```

Comment: I run "git diff" and get some outputs start with "+" and "-" sign, what are they stand for?

Comment: Lines that begin with `+` show new lines that you have added, while those beginning with `-` show lines that were in the file but have now been removed.

Comment: +1. Four. More. Votes. Note: coupling git diff with an external tool (like a Beyond Compare) can help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069490/git-diff-with-beyond-compare/2069950#2069950

Comment: ONE THOUSAND VOTES! You are now officially a git god (you were to me before the badge of course)

Comment: @VonC: thanks - nothing compared to your extraordinary work here, of course :)