# Why the conflict markers don't disappear with a git mergetool using Beyond compare 3?

Tags: git, beyondcompare3

I changed the merge tool to Beyond Compare.
I merge a file `a.txt` in '`test`' branch with file `a.txt` in `master` branch.
I want to update my `a.txt` in `master` branch with changes in `a.txt` in '`test`' branch.

When I input '`$git mergetool`', it shows the merge tool with the left is `LOCAL` and the right is `REMOTE`. When I merge changes in `REMOTE` to `LOCAL`, then I save and close BC3, I choose 'y' with the question '`Was the merge sucessful?`'.

Everything seems well.
However, when I check the `a.txt` in the master, it appears the conflict markers with `<<<<HEAD`. What's wrong with the merge?
I think I merged and saved it before, but **why the conflict markers not disappear?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't supposed to modified LOCAL, but only the file shown in the lower part of the Beyond compare diff GUI:

[image: http://donatstudios.com/assets/42/winebottler_beyond_compare_3way_merge.png]

If you don't, the mergetool consider you didn't made any modification to the file, which will keep its conflict markers.

Comment: So, how can I merge using BC3? I'm working in Win7/Vista. Thanks

Comment: @lolyoshi By doing your merge in the *lower* part of the BC3 GUI, as illustrated by the picture. Make sure you configure `mergetool` as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/9525491/6309.