# Git compare in sourcetree - associating commits to tabs in beyond compare?

Tags: windows, git, atlassian-sourcetree, beyondcompare

Using Sourcetree, I see two commits.

I select them both :

[image]

Now I click on the `External Diff` button :

[image]

The External tool is `Beyond Compare` :

[image]

But when BeyondCompare is opened, I don't see any info which can indicate which side belongs to which commit : ( *I only see some random characters*)

[image]

**Question:**

How can I know which tab indicates which commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check the filename: it could be prefixed with `LOCAL.` or `REMOTE.`, as [I show here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19445984/6309).

The order, for Beyond Compare, should always be `LOCAL-REMOTE` (for a diff), with in your case:

- `LOCAL`: the oldest commit you have selected
- `REMOTE`: the most recent commit you have selected.

(as noted by the [OP Royi Namir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/859154/royi-namir) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59065606/git-compare-in-sourcetree-associating-commits-to-tabs-in-beyond-compare/59108731#comment104475793_59108731))

Comment: Just to emphesize :  it's not the _first_ commit that I select. even if I check A-B or B-A , the beyond compare display result is the same. so it's by chronological time. ( I've just checked).

Comment: @RoyiNamir Than you. I have edited the answer accordingly.