# Setting up Beyond Compare 4 in Visual Studio 2013 when using Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, beyondcompare

I'm trying to figure out how to configure BEYOND COMPARE 4 to use with Visual Studio 2013 with GIT.  NO matter how I seem to configure this it wants to use the VS2013 internal diff/merge tools.

Beyond Compare Install Directory

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 4
```

from git bash window

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\me>git --version
git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0

C:\Users\me>git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
rebase.autosquash=true
diff.tool=bc4
difftool.bc4.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 4\BComp.exe
merge.tool=bc4
mergetool.bc4.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 4\BComp.exe
core.editor="C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitExtensions.exe" fileeditor
core.autocrlf=true
credential.helper=!\"C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitCredentialWinStore/
git-credential-winstore.exe\"
user.name=me
user.email=me@email.com
gui.recentrepo=C:/DevSource/mercury

C:\Users\me>
```

Global gitcoinfig in GIT install / etc directory

```
[core]
    symlinks = false
    autocrlf = true
[color]
    diff = auto
    status = auto
    branch = auto
    interactive = true
[pack]
    packSizeLimit = 2g
[help]
    format = html
[http]
    sslCAinfo = /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
[sendemail]
    smtpserver = /bin/msmtp.exe

[rebase]
    autosquash = true
[diff]
    tool = bc4
[difftool "bc4"]
    path = C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Beyond Compare 4\\BComp.exe
[merge]
    tool = bc4
[mergetool "bc4"]
    path = C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Beyond Compare 4\\BComp.exe
```

Also tried changing the exe to BCompare.exe instead of BComp.exe but that didn't work either.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you get when you run `git mergetool`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I believe I found the answer in this post
[Git Diff with Beyond Compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069490/git-diff-with-beyond-compare) which so far seems to work.  The visual studio environment brings up the new BC4.0 IDE instead of the internal tools.

```
[diff]
    tool = bc4
[difftool "bc4"]
    cmd = \"c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 4/bcomp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[merge]
    tool = bc4
[mergetool "bc4"]
    cmd = \"c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 4/bcomp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\"
    trustExitCode = true
```