# Git environment variables documentation

Tags: git

I would like to make some changes to `git-difftool` for better support with `BeyondCompare`. I notice this Perl program use lots of ENV variables such as:

- `GIT_DIFF_TOOL`
- `GIT_DIFFTOOL_EXTCMD`
- `GIT_DIFFTOOL_DIRDIFF`
- `GIT_DIFFTOOL_PROMPT`
- `GIT_PAGER`

Unfortunately I did not find any documentation of these variables. Google is not my friend today...

**EDIT**

As answered by VonC, the above variables are related to `git-difftool--helper.sh`. I am still confused with `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF`. Git will launch `git-difftool--helper.sh` which iterates each 7-arguments. What are these arguments, where is the documentation related to it?

Comment: Where did you see it iterates around 7 args?

Comment: `git-difftool--helper.sh` lines `85..95`

Comment: Ok, I have edited the answer to add the documentation for the 7 parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note (update Q1 2017 with Git 2.12): `difftool` is no longer a perl program, but C builtin tool within Git.

See [commit 94d3997](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94d3997ecc09f36d17b9ad4b49c4709885e300f7) (25 Jan 2017) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit 019678d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/019678d6b1f83419cdc35e3d455175adce3a379c), [commit 03831ef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/03831ef7b5011cbedbcc67abe5f47762f37c6c21) (19 Jan 2017), and [commit be8a90e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be8a90e59ce4c7603207a8255284fdbbffff1a2e) (17 Jan 2017) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b7786bb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b7786bb4b09463641f3e39eca18aefc630ee4f38), 31 Jan 2017)</sup>

---

Original answer March 2015:

[`git-difftool.perl`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-difftool.perl) simply uses those environment variables to give the user the opportunity to override the config value you can see in "[Git Diff with Beyond Compare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3395497/6309)".

Those environment variables are used in [`git-difftool--helper.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9abc44b681a669c67d071d858c8aad21f65a0956/git-difftool--helper.sh), where they can override the local config.

[`diff config`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f53fc38c083da1a1d14f54713ffd8fd0965a2194/Documentation/diff-config.txt#L63-L68) mentions the config `diff.external` which can be overridden by the `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` environment variable.
That command is meant to be called with parameters as described **[under "git Diffs" of git](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f53fc38c083da1a1d14f54713ffd8fd0965a2194/Documentation/git.txt#L838)**.

That is where the 7 parameters are documented:

> #### '`GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF`'::

> When the environment variable '`GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF`' is set, the program named by it is called, instead of the diff invocation described above. For a path that is added, removed, or modified,
>
> '`GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF`' is called with 7 parameters:
>
> ```
> path old-file old-hex old-mode new-file new-hex new-mode
> ```
>
> where:
>
> - `<old|new>-file`:: are files `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` can use to read the contents of `<old|new>`,
> - `<old|new>-hex`:: are the 40-hexdigit SHA-1 hashes,
> - `<old|new>-mode`:: are the octal representation of the file modes.

---

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), the role of `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` is clarified.

See [commit 17bae89](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17bae894760b79b7e5a4225e0ffca256d3cc5704) (01 Sep 2020) by [Philippe Blain (`phil-blain`)](https://github.com/phil-blain).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cd332b2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd332b2a319f00db18b91201cc9a6fafc6adf649), 03 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`git.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17bae894760b79b7e5a4225e0ffca256d3cc5704): correct stale '`GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF`' description
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Philippe Blain</sup>

> In [fde97d8ac6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fde97d8ac63efa466dd48436d2178bd364b846de) ("Update documentation to remove incorrect `GIT_DIFF_OPTS` example.", 2006-11-27, Git v1.5.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fde97d8ac63efa466dd48436d2178bd364b846de)), the description of the '`GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF`' variable was moved from '`diff-format.txt`' to '`git.txt`', and the documentation was updated to remove a '`diff`' invocation **since Git did not use an external `diff` program anymore by default**.
>
> However, the description of '`GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF`' still mentions "instead of the diff invocation described above", which is confusing.
>
> Correct that outdated sentence.

`git` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/17bae894760b79b7e5a4225e0ffca256d3cc5704/Documentation/git.txt#L546-L548):

> ### `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF`:
>
> When the environment variable `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` is set, the program named by it is called to generate diffs, and Git does not use its builtin diff machinery.

---

It may be tempting to leave the help text `NULL` for a command line option that is either hidden or too obvious, but git subcmd -h and git subcmd `--help-all` would have segfaulted if done so.
Now (Git 2.43, Q4 2023), the help text is optional.

See [commit cd52d9e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd52d9e90f63a1a08023980d27f3004174d23655) (26 Aug 2023) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 27e2ea9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/27e2ea97da6addecb7e2d3c5f97a668276f3e951), 05 Sep 2023)</sup>

> ### [`parse-options`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd52d9e90f63a1a08023980d27f3004174d23655): allow omitting option help text
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> [1b68387](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b68387e026f81dcda330f721c0e54a8902ad4eb) ("[`builtin/receive-pack.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1b68387e026f81dcda330f721c0e54a8902ad4eb/builtin/receive-pack.c): use `parse_options` API", 2016-03-02, Git v2.9.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/77e075124acc3f1185a8b178aac479c8278780a5) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/72d917a7f9a5123ef7c0d6db306bbc0d385227e2)) added the options `--stateless-rpc`, `--advertise-refs` and `--reject-thin-pack-for-testing` with a `NULL` `help` string; [03831ef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/03831ef7b5011cbedbcc67abe5f47762f37c6c21) ("`difftool`: implement the functionality in the builtin", 2017-01-19, Git v2.12.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b7786bb4b09463641f3e39eca18aefc630ee4f38) listed in [batch #8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3c4ce8e69b4838efce72d090b85bbbbb6eacc5bc)) similarly added the "helpless" option `--prompt`.
> Presumably this was done because all four options are hidden and self-explanatory.
>
> They cause a `NULL` pointer dereference when using the option `--help-all` with their respective tool, though.
>
> Handle such options gracefully instead by turning the `NULL` pointer into an empty string at the top of the loop, always printing a newline at the end and passing through the separating newlines from the help text.

Comment: And what about the `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` variable?

Comment: @coin it is only used to override the config `diff.external` (https://github.com/git/git/blob/f53fc38c083da1a1d14f54713ffd8fd0965a2194/Documentation/diff-config.txt#L63-L68)

Answer (score -1):

I use `git` and `Beyond Compare` and I never used any script to configure them.

An excerpt from the output of `git config --global --list`:

```
difftool.bcomp.cmd=/usr/local/bin/bcomp "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$BASE" "$MERGED"
difftool.bcomp.trustexitcode=true
diff.tool=bcomp
```

You need to install the command line tools of `Beyond Compare`. This is very simple: just select the "Install Command Line Tools..." command from the menu of Beyond Compare and follow the instructions (it asks you for your password because it needs to operate in system directories).

When it finishes it displays:

> **Successfully installed command line tools.**
>
> /usr/local/bin/bcomp:
>   Launches comparison and waits for it to complete.
>
> /usr/local/bin/bcompare:
>   Launches comparison and returns immediately.

Then you configure `git` using:

```
git config --global --add difftool.bcomp.cmd '/usr/local/bin/bcomp "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$BASE" "$MERGED"'
git config --global --add difftool.bcomp.trustexitcode true
git config --global --add diff.tool bcomp
```

Check if everything is set up correctly:

```
git difftool file.txt
```

(replace `file.txt` with the name of a real file that was changed in your repository).

Additionally, if you run:

```
git config --global --add mergetool.prompt false
```

then `git difftool` will launch the selected diff program (`bcomp` in this case) without asking for confirmation (as it does by default).

Comment: Well, I admit you can use beyond compare without any external script but in my case I want to bypass some limitations: 1. In difftool, load all files in beyond compare in separated tabs, 2. Support for dir-diff `git difftool --dir-diff`, 3. Latencies (with cygwin on Windows, it takes about 2 second to launch Beyond Compare for each file)

Comment: Actually my question was not about Beyond Compare :)

Comment: What is your question about? You ask about some variables used by some Perl script you didn't provide.

Comment: my question is about `git-difftool--helper.sh` located in `/usr/libexec/git-core/`

Comment: Well, I couldn't guess that.