# Git compare tags with bcompare

Tags: git, unix, redhat, beyondcompare

I'm trying to compare 2 git tags with bcompare.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3395497/6479770) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3211829/6479770). But it's not working.

What I've done in gitconfig :

```
[diff]
    tool = bc3
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "bc3"]
    cmd = \"/appli/bcompare_4.2.4/bin/bcompare\"
```

But when I do

```
git diff tag1 tag2
```

Differences are displayed on console. I want to see each different file in a bcompare tab. How can I do ?

Comment: The fact that `cmd` does not contain a complete command is suspicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the path to `bcompare` in the cmd is rigth. Append `$LOCAL` and `$REMOTE`.

```
[difftool "bc3"]
    cmd = \"/appli/bcompare_4.2.4/bin/bcompare\" $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

Run `git difftool tag1 tag2` to invoke the difftool.

Comment: I did the test but there is no changes. My `$LOCAL` and `$REMOTE` are empty, is there normal ?

Comment: @A.Pissicat Remove both `\"` in `cmd` and have a try. Besides, try `/appli/bcompare_4.2.4/bin/bcompare foo bar` in the console and test if `bcompare` can be invoked as expected. `foo` and `bar` are two files on the disk.

Comment: It's working now. Just a last question, actually it opens all files one by one, is there a way to open all files in multiple tabs ?

Comment: @A.Pissicat Does it get to work after `\"` are removed? I don't know how to open all files in multiple tabs. Maybe `bcompare` offers some command-line options to support this feature. If there is any, you could add the option in `cmd`.

Comment: Git doesn't provide a way to launch all files in multiple tabs. However, you can launch the diff of all files in the Folder Compare using the command: `git difftool --dir-diff` or `git difftool -d`.