# how to tar a directory without parent directory

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I want to compress the contents of:

```
/ebs1/xxx/aaa/bbb/
```

So, all the files and folders inside "bbb" I want to be compressed to a file named "xxx.tar.gz" I am using:

```
tar -zcvf "xxx.tar.gz" "/ebs1/xxx/aaa/bbb/"
```

It's ok. But when I open the file "xxx.tar.gz" the tree directories start at

```
/ebs1 -> /xxx -> /aaa -> /bbb ->
```

and after this I can see the content.

Is it possible to tell tar not to include the parent directories in the compressed files, so when I extract it I dont need to open all directories to get to my content?

Comment: Better for [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions)

Comment: Why don't you `cd /ebs1/xxx/aaa/bbb/` and tar the current directory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [tar: add all files and directories in current directory INCLUDING .svn and so on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651791/tar-add-all-files-and-directories-in-current-directory-including-svn-and-so-on)

Comment: huuum! Great idea.  So I use cd and then I must use tar -zcvf "xxx.tar.gz" ?

Comment: I tried -->> tar -zcvf "/ebs1/xxx/aaa/bbb/backup.tar.gz" -C "/ebs1/xxx/aaa/bbb/" <<-- but did not work! Why?

Comment: Try => `tar -zcvf backup.tar.gz -C /ebs1/xxx/aaa/bbb/` OR this => `cd /ebs1/xxx/aaa/bbb/` then `tar -zcvf backup.tar.gz .`

Comment: did not work Sir Rahil

Comment: Did you try `tar` on current directory?

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
tar -czvf xxx.tar.gz -C /ebs1/xxx/aaa/bbb .
```