# how can I create an archive before git svn dcommit?

Tags: git, svn, githooks, dcommit

I'm trying to create a zip archive of my project when I push to the svn server. My old setup would use a post-receive hook on the remote git repo to do this. However, I'm now using svn and I don't own the svn server so I can't put anything over there. I've set up the following pre-push hook but this isn't running on `git svn dcommit`:

```
$cat .git/hooks/pre-push
#!/bin/sh
git archive -o foo_bar.zip --prefix foo_bar/ master
```

Any ideas on which hook I could use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no such hook, how about creating an alias instead?

```
dcm = "!f(){ git archive -o foo_bar.zip --prefix foo_bar/ master; git svn dcommit; }; f"
```

Comment: nice. It works. Now, I just need to brush up on git commands to figure out why it works :)

Comment: It's simple, actually: there's just a one-line function there, `f(){ ...; }`, which has the commands you want to run, and right after the `f` to call the function and execute the commands. This is `bash` syntax btw.

Answer (score 2):

You are using [git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn), right? You haven't cited it anywhere, so I'm not sure you are. Those `git-hooks` won't work with pure svn, you must be using git! It can be obvious, but better to be sure.

As to your problem, you could probably use a `post-commit` hook: once you finished a commit you zip things up. The downside to this, is that you won't have the zip file added to your repo.

If you need the zip on the repository, use the `pre-commit` hook and `stash` your tree. You can easily archive this tree, add the zipped file to the git index, and your done!

This answer might help you scripting this: [Git archive of repository with uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766600/git-archive-of-repository-with-uncommitted-changes).

Comment: I believe I'm just using the plain vanilla git which now includes svn support. I was hoping to not have to create an archive every time I commit a change.