# This magic line of Bash is indecipherable to me, can someone explain what it's doing?

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I found it on this thread:
[Best way to parse command line args in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786984/best-way-to-parse-command-line-args-in-bash)

And I'm trying to use it in this code:
https://github.com/flyingfishfuse/bash-scripts/blob/master/debootstrap-ubuntu-18-04.sh

And this is the part I don't understand, specifically the third line.

```
[ $# = 0 ] && help
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  CMD=$(grep -m 1 -Po "^## *$1, --\K[^= ]*|^##.* --\K${1#--}(?:[= ])" go.sh | sed -e "s/-/_/g")
  if [ -z "$CMD" ]; then echo "ERROR: Command '$1' not supported"; exit 1; fi
  shift; eval "$CMD" $@ || shift $? 2> /dev/null
```

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: What do you find confusing?  It is assigning a value to CMD.  The value it assigns is the output of a badly written grep piped to sed, which should have used `tr`, which should tell you that the code should be avoided, not emulated. The only thing here which might be confusing is the regex, which absolutely should be simplified.  Maybe the `${1#--}` is confusing you as well.  I would not emulate this code.  Avoid it.  The `eval "$CMD" $@ || shift $?` should send you running, screaming.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I find it confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer explains the rest of the script, I'll try to explain the grep.

- `grep`

  - `-m1` - print first match only.
  - `-P` - use perl regex flavor.
  - `-o` - print only the string that matched.
  - `"^## *$1, --\K[^= ]*|^##.* --\K${1#--}(?:[= ])"`

    - The `|` or two regexes. So we search for one regex or the other.
    - The `\K` "resets the line position". Basically it means that with `-o` it will print the result from `\K` to the end that matched the regex. It's often used together `grep -Po 'blabla\Kblabla'. For example`echo abcde | grep -P 'ab\K..'`will print`de`.
  - `^## *$1, --\K[^= ]*`

    - Search for a line that goes `##<zero or more spaces><first argument>, --<anything but not spaces or '=', zero or more times>`. And the part `<anything but not spaces...>` is printed out. So from `--` to the next space or `=` is printed out.
  - `^##.* --\K${1#--}(?:[= ])`

    - `(?: ... )` is a grouping in perl that "does not use memory". The `(?:something)` is the same as `(something)`.
    - Search for lines that go `##<anything> --<first argument with leading '--' deleted><'=' or space, that will be not included in the output>`
  - So basically grep wants to find something like `##    first_arg, --<this here>` or `## blabla --<first_arg>` where `first_arg` is the current first argument in the script and it will output the part inside `<` `>`.
- `sed`

  - `"s/-/_/g"` - Just substitutes all `-` with `_`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time on that :P I would have needed manpages for \K and a few other things, and on mobile it wasn’t worth the trouble.

Comment: Thank you, I'm writing this partially to recover lost knowledge and partially to teach skiddies. I am adding all that to explain the regex and linking your answer in the comments.

As you can see there is a year long gap in commits and before then it was more like 7 years...

Answer (score 0):

`bash(1)` isn’t all that “magic,” though it certainly makes its users feel like wizards! The key to deciphering it is to know which manpages to look at. Or, if you are a language person (like me), to realize that bash is one little glue language; a bunch of other little languages are sprinkled on top of it in the form of little tools like `grep(1)`, `sed(1)`, `awk(1)`, `cut(1)`, etc.

So, let’s dig in:

```
[ $# = 0 ] && help
```

This says, run the `[` test command; if it succeeds, run the help command. `$#` is the number of arguments. Run `help test` at your shell to get a good idea of its workings (`help` only works for builtins—for the rest you need `man(1)`).

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
```

The beginning of a while loop. To note: most modern bash programmers would use either `[[ $# > 0 ]]` (unless they need ti be POSIX-sh compatible) or `(($# > 0))`.

```
CMD=$(...)
```

Run the stuff in parens and store the output in CMD (the manual for bash clarifies how this works).

```
grep ... go.sh
```

Searches `go.sh` for a particular pattern (see `man re_format` for the gory details of regular expressions, and `man grep` for what the options do—for example, `-o` means print only the match instead of the whole line).

```
| sed ...
```

Output the results of grep as the input to sed. `man sed` is a good resource for its little language. `s/-/_/g` substitutes all `-` for `_`; a more idiomatic way to do that would be to use tr instead of sed: `tr - _`.

```
if [ -z ... ]
```

Test if the argument is empty. The rest of the if logs a message and exits.

```
shift
```

Pops a command line argument off of `$@`, so now there’s one less.

```
eval "$CMD" "$@"
```

Run the CMD string (better would be to use an array here) with the remaining arguments.

```
|| shift $? 2>/dev/null
```

If it fails, shift off as many arguments as the exit code (`$?`), and redirect error messages to `/dev/null` (such as when there aren’t enough arguments to shift).

This part is a little bizarre, and probably only makes sense in the context of the application. Generally, exit codes don’t tell you what to shift. But you could program something that way.

Comment: The real magic is in the parameter expansion and the use of `grep -P` with `\K` and lookaheads.

Comment: holy crap you are awesome! I'm rewriting that whole part now thanks to your wisdom and its going to be CLEAN AND READABLE!

Comment: @moop thanks! I do a lot of bash programming; there *are* (contrary to some beliefs) best practices (esp. for readability and error-handling). Some of my scripts are on GitHub, which should be linked in my profile. Also see [strict mode](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/), the [advanced guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html), [shell style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml), and this [incredible wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide)

Comment: does my script measure up to any quality standards?

Comment: Careful with the ABS, it's a mixed bag.

Comment: @tripleee oh agreed; some of the stuff in there should make you run screaming :P

Answer (score 0):

```
CMD=$(grep -m 1 -Po "^## *$1, --\K[^= ]*|^##.* --\K${1#--}(?:[= ])" go.sh | sed -e "s/-/_/g")
```

The above line is grepping max 1 line (-m 1) from file `go.sh` only matching the regular expression (`-Po`)  : 
`"^## *$1, --\K[^= ]*|^##.* --\K${1#--}(?:[= ])"`   (`$1` being substituted by the script argument that is being processed currently inside the while loop )
Then the result of the grep command is piped to `sed` where each '-' is changed to '_' : `sed -e "s/-/_/g"` . And the resulting string of this operation becomes the value of the CMD variable.

Comment: This solved the regex question! I was getting confusing results from a debugger and its because that $1 was indeed being processed by the shell!