# Any tool to see differences between version in git

Tags: git, ubuntu, diff

Is there any tool out there which enables me to see differences between different versions in git? and the differences is shown in-line in a file? E.g. like the way eclipse shows 2 files differences?

Thank you.

Comment: http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/ - http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/2/13/843394

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-visual-diff-program/949242#949242

Comment: Any good diff tool for ubuntu? for git?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lot of different tools.

`git difftool --tool=$TOOL <REV1>..<REV2> -- FileName`

Where `<REV1>` and `<REV2>` are any valid revision identifiers according to git-rev-parse, and $TOOL is the command line invocation of any number of tools for which git has drivers.

To use a tool by default, `git config diff.tool $TOOL`

Answer (score 0):

Use Beyond Compare. Best tool I've ever used. Works perfect with GIT

Command in git will be: git mergetool. For standard git compare use: gitk

put this in your c:\program files\git\etc\gitconfig file:

[merge]
    tool = bc3 # This will be the default merge tool invoked by git mergetool.
[mergetool "bc3"]
    cmd = 'c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 3/bcomp.exe' \

```
    "$PWD/$LOCAL" \
    "$PWD/$REMOTE" \
    "$PWD/$BASE" \
```

"$PWD/$MERGED" 
    keepBackup = false
    trustExitCode = FALSE

[More Info](http://cbilson.blogspot.com/2008/10/using-beyond-compare-as-git-mergetool.html)