# How can I do case insensitive git diffing while also doing `git diff --color`?

Tags: git, case-insensitive, git-diff

Is it possible to do a case insensitive `git diff` while also doing `git diff --color-words`? Or do I need to use an external diff program while doing `git diff --color-words`?

( note: if all you want is git diff case insensitive please go to this question  [How to perform case insensitive diff in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17380029/52074) )

Comment: The fact that the word "case" does not appear in the manpage in that context doesn't bode well for you...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to perform case insensitive diff in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380029/how-to-perform-case-insensitive-diff-in-git)

Comment: @Anto: possible but this question is 2 years older...

Answer (score 12):

```
GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF='diff -ipu "$2" "$5" #' git diff --ext-diff
```

Or, in a nicer fashion without the # hack I used there:

```
echo 'diff -ipu "$2" "$5"' >myscript; chmod a+x myscript;
GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF='./myscript' git diff --ext-diff
```

I agree it would be nicest if git-diff would just have an `-i` option...

Comment: This doesn't get you color, or a word-diff... wdiff would get you the later, but not in the colored form.

Comment: Hook it up with a script that calls wdiff, and applies color, such as [cwdiff](http://www.google.de/search?q="cwdiff"+"hxtools")

Comment: This looks promising, but if there is a binary file in the repositiory, it fails with `fatal: the external diff application disapeared` and does not display any output.

Comment: In msysgit I'm getting `fatal: external diff died, stopping at path/to/file.txt` after first file.

Comment: You can add a trailing `| cat` at the end of the script to avoid the failure message, as explained in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-a-visual-diff-program]

Comment: you can add the argument `--color=always` to the diff command to force colors, e.g. `echo 'diff --color=always -ipu "$2" "$5"' >myscript`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to perform case-insensitive diff, although not with the --color-word option as the OP asked for. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380029/how-to-perform-case-insensitive-diff-in-git/17380104#17380104) to my own question.