# How to perform case insensitive diff in Git

Tags: git, diff, case-insensitive

`git diff` does not support a case-insensitive comparison of files. Google shows a very few people asking for that feature, and that too only in combination with some other `git diff` switch, like with `-G` or with `--color-words`.

I don't care for other switches, as long as `git diff` can show me the case-insensitive diff.

Since I didn't see any specific question towards that, and since I found a solution after an hour researching this problem, I am adding this question and the answer.

Comment: `git diff` also does not support case-insensitive comparison of **file names**. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do case insensitive git diffing while also doing \`git diff --color\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998474/how-can-i-do-case-insensitive-git-diffing-while-also-doing-git-diff-color)

Comment: @DanBechard I'd just rely on Git deciding that those are "renames." It adds very little noise to the diff output.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The solution is to use `git difftool`. With the following config command, I can add a custom `diff` tool called `idiff` for Git to use:

`git config --global difftool.idiff.cmd 'diff -i $LOCAL $REMOTE'`

With this customization, I can see the case-insensitive comparison like so:

`git difftool --tool idiff <other diff options> <Git references or files>`

Eg.

`git difftool -t idiff HEAD~1 -- my_schema.sql`

Since `git difftool` prompts (for yes/no) every time before invoking the the tool, either use `-y` switch for `difftool` or add this config option to avoid the prompt:

`git config --global difftool.prompt 0`

*UPDATE* (2021/11/26): Here's a consolidated configuration I use, that allows me to use `git idiff` command that behaves almost identical to how `git diff` behaves.

```
git config --global difftool.idiff.cmd 'diff --unified=3 --color=always --ignore-case $LOCAL $REMOTE | less --raw-control-chars'
git config --global difftool.prompt 0
git config --global alias.idiff 'difftool --tool idiff'
```

Comment: but git-gui uses 'git diff' and not 'git difftool', so git-gui still shows all case sensitive differences ..

Comment: You can install `colordiff` first (e.g. `sudo apt-get install colordiff`) and then replace `diff -i $LOCAL $REMOTE` with `diff -i -u $LOCAL $REMOTE | colordiff` for colored unified diffs, i.e. normal Git style.

Comment: i added some more options to the `diff` command `git config --global difftool.idiff.cmd 'diff -i --unified --ignore-space-change --ignore-blank-lines --ignore-all-space $LOCAL $REMOTE'`. see `man diff` for more info on what the additional options are.

Comment: i was trying to redirect the output to a file... but it kept hanging until i did `git config --global difftool.prompt 0`.

Comment: can add `--color=always` as an option to `diff` too instead of piping to `colordiff` (and then use with `less -r` for pagination)

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Gurjeet Singh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17380104/241211), and caw's [`colordiff` comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380029/how-to-perform-case-insensitive-diff-in-git/17380104#comment69272547_17380104), in Windows I did the following to get it all tied together:

1. If needed, install Strawberry Perl distribution for Windows. Any Windows Perl distribution should work, but Strawberry Perl is free software/open source and comes with batteries included. Heed caution with the Web site result because there's a NSFW site with a similar domain IIRC. Use Google instead of guessing.
2. Install MinGW/MSYS. Git for Windows already comes with a build of MSYS so you might be able to just use its `make`, but your mileage may vary.
3. Download and install the `colordiff` Perl script. I edited the Makefile to change the install location to `~/bin` and `~/etc` (where `~` is `%USERPROFILE%`) because `~/bin` is already in my `PATH`. Adjust as needed.
4. (cmd.exe) Edit your registry environment variables (search start menu for environment variables) and add `.PL` to `PATHEXT` (and whatever `bin/` you used for `PATH` if necessary).
5. (cmd.exe) Create a bash script (e.g., `~/bin/colordiffless.bash`) that passes any arguments on to `colordiff.pl` (`colordiff` accepts diff options and passes them on automatically) and pipes through `less`. The color codes output by `colordiff` are ANSI, which cmd.exe will not understand, but `less` does. You also restore Git's pager behavior this way (configure `LESS` environment variable if necessary).

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   colordiff.pl "$@" | less
   ```
6. Setup the alias as Gurjeet did, except instead of invoking `diff` directly, invoke your bash script. The color codes output are ANSI so you'll need something to convert them. I happen to know that MSYS `less` will do just that, and you also preserve the pager behavior of Git!

   ```
   git config --global difftool.cldiff.cmd "colordiffless.bash -ui $LOCAL $REMOTE"
   ```

   (from cmd.exe, so the double-quotes are literal and the `$LOCAL` and `$REMOTE` are literal text too)
7. Finally, alias the `difftool` command so you can type a single, custom command instead of the `difftool` command:

   ```
   git config --global alias.cldiff "difftool -y -t cldiff"
   ```

### Edit

I was mistaken about the pager behavior coming back. `difftool` invokes the command for each file so instead of getting a single pager output with every diff, you will get a pager for each file. To solve that, you will likely want to wrap `difftool -y` in a script and pipe its entire output to `less` instead.

Answer (score 0):

A bit fixed - no need to have useless colors in patch:

```
git config --global difftool.idiff.cmd 'diff --unified=3 --color=never --ignore-case $LOCAL $REMOTE | less --raw-control-chars'
git config --global difftool.prompt 0
git config --global alias.idiff 'difftool --tool idiff'
```

And then it should be possible to generate nice HTML from by for example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- Make sure to load the highlight.js CSS file before the Diff2Html CSS file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.7.1/styles/github.min.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/diff2html/bundles/css/diff2html.min.css"
    />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/diff2html/bundles/js/diff2html-ui.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <script>
    function show(diffString) {
      var targetElement = document.getElementById('myDiffElement');
      var configuration = {
        drawFileList: true,
        fileListToggle: false,
        fileListStartVisible: false,
        fileContentToggle: false,
        matching: 'lines',
        outputFormat: 'side-by-side',
        synchronisedScroll: true,
        highlight: true,
        renderNothingWhenEmpty: false,
      };
      var diff2htmlUi = new Diff2HtmlUI(targetElement, diffString, configuration);
      diff2htmlUi.draw();
      diff2htmlUi.highlightCode();
    }
  </script>
  <body>
    <div id="myDiffElement"></div>
    <textarea onchange="show(this.value)" rows=30 cols=160></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70640721/visual-diff-patch-editor question - simple page transforming -/+ rows by 2 functions (regExp for example) to be similar (replace whitespaces, etc.) and filtering only results different after this transformation on both sides...

Comment: https://meldmerge.org/ or https://github.com/timbrel/GitSavvy looks interesting...

Answer (score 0):

To compare two Git commits regardless of case, I create archive files and compare the file contents with an external tool - in this case WinMerge (Portable):

```
git archive 991f70fe --format=zip > Archive/arcL.zip
git archive cffd466a --format=zip > Archive/arcR.zip
WinMergePortable.exe /ignorecase /ignoreeol /m Full Archive/arcL.zip Archive/arcR.zip
```

or

```
git archive master --format=zip > Archive/arcL.zip
git archive master --format=zip --remote=ssh://user@192.168.1.2/volume1/git/Tools20 > Archive/arcR.zip
WinMergePortable.exe /ignorecase /ignoreeol /m Full Archive/arcL.zip Archive/arcR.zip
```

The last command opens the GUI that shows the differences.

Comment: Creating archives of the commits seems a bit too heavy-handed to me.