# How to ignore/revert changes of case in file-content?

Tags: bash, git, git-bash, case-insensitive

I am versioning Microsoft Access VBA code, which is in general case insensitive. However changes the case of variable names happen every now in then (by the Access compiler or by the developer). This often leads to huge change set in my git workspace.

How can I revert or ignore changes, that only concern upper- or lowercase of file contents?

An example:

```
git init
echo "public sub example()\nend sub" > mdlExample.ACM
#                ^-- lower e
git add --all
git commit --all --message "Initial Commit"
echo "public sub Example()\nend sub" > mdlExample.ACM
#                ^-- upper E
```

I would love something like:

```
git restore --only-case-changes # not working
```

And then:

```
git status
> On branch master
> nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: Did you try this yet? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52950/how-to-make-git-ignore-changes-in-case

Comment: @Jay Most of the users only are concerned about *file names*. In my case, the *file content* is relevant.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Thank you for the quick reply.

Answer (score 5):

Consider changing `example="example"` to `Example="Example"`. How do you propose Git could decide which case change to ignore here? Now consider code snippets in comments, or stored as strings for code generators.  I get wanting Git to make an annoying chore go away, but I think if you try to imagine telling Git exactly what you want you'll understand the context of your question a little better.

> How can I revert or ignore changes, that only concern upper- or lowercase of file contents

When you want to *temporarily* ignore changes, when you want to do a diff or a blame without seeing those changes, you can use a "textconv" filter that normalizes the text you diff.  I use those to do things like strip embedded timestamps out of generated html when diffing, quickest to hand atm is

```
[diff "doc-html"]
    textconv = "sed  's,<span class=\"version\">Factorio [0-9.]*</span>,,;s,<[^/>][^>]*>,\\n&,g'"
    wordRegex = "<[^>]*\\>|[^< \\t\\n]*"
```

in `.git/config`, and

```
doc-html/*.html diff=doc-html
*.cfg -diff
```

in `.git/info/attributes`.

so my what-changed diffs don't show me things I don't care about.

If you want to see the results of a diff ignoring case, try

```
[diff "nocase"]
        textconv="tr A-Z a-z"
```

and drop `* diff=nocase` (or maybe`*.vba diff=nocase`) into `.git/info/attributes`. When you're done, take it out.

but for merging, my leadoff example should convince you that Git automatically and silently making case changes in repo content, even just in the text that looks like identifiers, is a Bad Idea. When there's a conflict, not just a one-sided change but two different changes, it's still going to take some human judgement to decide what the result should be. Fortunately, with any decent merge tool, resolving simple conflicts is down around subsecond range each.

Comment: With `textconv = "sed  's,.,\\L&,g'"` your solution works well for `git diff`. However `git status` will still list all files.

Comment: You will need a converter which is smarter than `sed` : a lexer that can make the distinction between "names in code" vs "strings or comments" is probably enough ; and a content filter as @VonC suggested, so that this filter applies to the actual content stored in git.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to `git restore` anything: You could setup a [clean content filter driver as illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28446440/6309), which will automatically convert those cases on `git diff`/`git commit`.
That means:

- you won't even see there is a diff
- you won't add /commit anything because of that content filter driver.

[image: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/images/clean.png]
<sup>Image from "[Keyword Expansion](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion)" section of the "[ProGit book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2)"</sup>

This is done through:

- a [`.gitattributes` filter declaration](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_filter), which means you can associate it only to certain files (through, for instance, their extension)

  ```sh
  *.ACM filter=ignoreCase
  ```
- a local [`git config filter.<driver>.clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-filterltdrivergtclean) to declare the actual script (which should be in your `PATH`)

  ```sh
  git config filter.ignoreCase.clean ignoreCase.sh

  # that give a .git/config file with:

  [filter "ignoreCase"]
    clean = ignoreCase.sh
  ```

The trick is:

Can you write a script which takes the content of an ACM file as input and produces the same ACM file as output, but with its strings converted?
You can have the [filename in those scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60905975/6309) so you can do a diff and detect if said difference has to be adjusted, but you still need to write the right command to replace only "`xxx`" strings when their case changes in ACM files.

Note: [jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731/jthill) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63067288/how-to-ignore-revert-changes-of-case-in-file-content/63754413?noredirect=1#comment112743318_63754413) to set the [`merge.renormalize`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-mergerenormalize) config settings to tell Git that canonical representation of files in the repository has changed over time.

Comment: You're also going to want to set [`merge.renormalize`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-mergerenormalize). For the normalization filter a flex for is probably quickest to implement reasonably safely.

Comment: @jthill Thank you. Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the answer from this StackOverflow question:

[How to perform case insensitive diff in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380029/how-to-perform-case-insensitive-diff-in-git/17380104#17380104)

Maybe you can write a script to go and do the diff comparison for each commit and then add those commits to your branch.  It may not be as simple as you like but maybe it will simplify the display of the changes to allow you to get to the case insensitive changes quicker?

Comment: I did not consider the `difftool` yet. But maybe it could be helpful when building a scripted solution for my issue.