# Is it possibly to apply a patch, ignoring case?

Tags: git, diff, patch

[`diff` has a `--ignore-case`](http://ss64.com/bash/diff.html) option. Is there an equivalent which I can use to apply a given [patch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) to a file, where the environment has differing letter case (as well as whitespace) from the files I used to obtain the patch?

Ideally, I'd like this directly in git (rebase / cherry pick etc.), but I'd also be fine with a manual solution.

Comment: The `diff` you're referring to is a bash command not a git command. As you can see in [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff), there is no `--ignore-case` flag, there are other `-ignore...` flags that may be suitable to your needs.

Comment: @Harmelodic yes, I know. That's why I said, _ideally_ I'd like something that works directly in git, but since the bash commands seem better prepared for case issues I asked about that.

Comment: Possibly check out these other questions asking the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998474/how-can-i-do-case-insensitive-git-diffing OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380029/how-to-perform-case-insensitive-diff-in-git