# diff to detect only case changes

Tags: version-control, diff, git-diff

Is there a simple way to have a diff between two versions of a file, showing only those lines/words that differ by a change to upper-/lowercase? All other differences should be omitted.

Background: I have a VBA project under version control (git) and Microsoft's editor tends to [change casing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1064858) every time a new variable is declared. I want to identify (and possibly count) such changes in order to prevent them from being committed.

Comment: What if a new line references a variable that changed case?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen This situation is not required to be recognized by the diff.

Comment: I'm guessing that writing such a difftool might not be too complex. I don't know of any already built that does just this.

Comment: I'll see if I can whip up a small tool for you. If I can I'll put it on github so you can download the code and tweak it to your requirements.

Comment: Here's a small tool you can try - https://github.com/lassevk/CaseDiff

Comment: Apologies, if you already tried it I introduced a bug in rewriting some code, it should be fixed now.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That's a great tool you've written! I am adding it as a difftool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a suggestion [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4999081) I have done it as follows, using basic Linux scripting tools:

```
GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF='diff -p -U 0 "$2" "$5" | cat #' git diff --ext-diff >  cdiff
GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF='diff -ip -U 0 "$2" "$5" | cat #' git diff --ext-diff > idiff

diff idiff cdiff | grep '^> [+-] '
```

The code makes first a case-sensitive diff `cdiff`, second a case-insensitive diff `idiff`. The case-only changes consist then of the lines in `cdiff` which are not contained in `idiff`.