# adding winmerge as mergetool in git

Tags: git

I am getting an error saying that

```
fatal bad config file line 24 in .git/config
```

Here is what I have in my config file..

```
[mergetool "winmerge"]
        name = WinMerge
        trustExitCode = true
        cmd = "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe" -u -e -dl \"Local\" dr \"Remote\" $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED
```

line 24 is the line starting with "cmd = "...

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

I tried to follow [this](https://gist.github.com/shawndumas/6158524)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with '/' instad of `\`:

```
cmd = "C:/Program Files (x86)/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe" -u -e -dl \"Local\" dr \"Remote\" $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED
```

Note that, [as I noted before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1884517/6309) ([details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30699239/6309)), since git 2.5+, a simpler config shoud be enough:

```
git config diff.tool winmerge
```

[git itself knows about the right `mergetool.cmd` syntax](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e4f2373b295e19dbc1a6bd0e743f65b500b7bda#diff-73dc2228641730b167bcce27569caafeR10) to use with winmerge.

Comment: I tried that but now its giving me a new error saying that merge.tool is not configured.  . ... No known merge tool is available.

Comment: @psj01 What is the version of your git? Also, if you try that (ie. just `git config diff.tool winmerge`), you need to edit your config first and remove the all `mergetool "winmerge"` section.

Comment: git version is version 1.9.5.msysgit.1

i did remove all that stuff.. before i did git config diff.tool winmerge..

Comment: @psj01 simply unzip https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.8.4.windows.1/PortableGit-2.8.4-64-bit.7z.exe anywhere you want (no setup or installation required), add it to your %PATH% and try again. git 2.8.4 is more than 2.5. 1.9.5 is not.

Comment: @psj01 in your CMD session, type `set PATH=C:\path\to\git2.8.4\bin;%PATH%`. Check with `git --version`. Then try again the git config (after cleaning up your local config which is in `.git/config`)

Comment: when i type in set PATH=C:\path\to\git2.8.4\bin;%PATH%

I get error saying sh.exe":fg: %PATH%: no such job

Comment: @psj01 No need for a bash here. Try it in a regular CMD session (Type the Windows key+R, then cmd)