# Using git diff, how can I get added and modified lines numbers?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

Assuming I have a text file

```
alex
bob
matrix
will be removed
git repo
```

and I have updated it to be

```
alex
new line here
another new line
bob
matrix
git
```

Here, I have added lines number (2,3) and updated line number (6)

How can I get these line numbers info using git diff or any other git command?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

`git diff --stat` will show you the output you get when committing stuff which is the one you are referring to I guess.

```
git diff --stat
```

For showing exactly the line numbers that has been changed you can use

```bash
git blame -p <file> | grep "Not Committed Yet"
```

And the line changed will be the last number before the ending parenthesis in the result. Not a clean solution though :(

Comment: stat only display how many lines are inserted/deleted/updated. But I need to know which line numbers

Comment: This seemed to be a harder problem than it should be, but I managed to get it by using git blame and grep. See my updated answer

Comment: One should usually call 'git blame -p' if the output is to be processed by other programs such as 'awk' or 'grep'.

Comment: git blame won't catch removed lines

Comment: @Sedrik can you help me to figure out this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839632/how-to-identify-line-modifications-separately-from-deletions-in-git-log]

Comment: Why is this marked as correct when it doesn't do what OP asked for?

Answer (score 33):

Here's a bash function to calculate the resulting line numbers from a diff:

```bash
diff-lines() {
    local path=
    local line=
    while read; do
        esc=$'\033'
        if [[ $REPLY =~ ---\ (a/)?.* ]]; then
            continue
        elif [[ $REPLY =~ \+\+\+\ (b/)?([^[:blank:]$esc]+).* ]]; then
            path=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        elif [[ $REPLY =~ @@\ -[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?\ \+([0-9]+)(,[0-9]+)?\ @@.* ]]; then
            line=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        elif [[ $REPLY =~ ^($esc\[[0-9;]*m)*([\ +-]) ]]; then
            echo "$path:$line:$REPLY"
            if [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} != - ]]; then
                ((line++))
            fi
        fi
    done
}
```

It can produce output such as:

```
$ git diff | diff-lines
http-fetch.c:1: #include "cache.h"
http-fetch.c:2: #include "walker.h"
http-fetch.c:3: 
http-fetch.c:4:-int cmd_http_fetch(int argc, const char **argv, const char *prefix)
http-fetch.c:4:+int main(int argc, const char **argv)
http-fetch.c:5: {
http-fetch.c:6:+       const char *prefix;
http-fetch.c:7:        struct walker *walker;
http-fetch.c:8:        int commits_on_stdin = 0;
http-fetch.c:9:        int commits;
http-fetch.c:19:        int get_verbosely = 0;
http-fetch.c:20:        int get_recover = 0;
http-fetch.c:21: 
http-fetch.c:22:+       prefix = setup_git_directory();
http-fetch.c:23:+
http-fetch.c:24:        git_config(git_default_config, NULL);
http-fetch.c:25: 
http-fetch.c:26:        while (arg < argc && argv[arg][0] == '-') {
fetch.h:1: #include "config.h"
fetch.h:2: #include "http.h"
fetch.h:3: 
fetch.h:4:-int cmd_http_fetch(int argc, const char **argv, const char *prefix);
fetch.h:4:+int main(int argc, const char **argv);
fetch.h:5: 
fetch.h:6: void start_fetch(const char* uri);
fetch.h:7: bool fetch_succeeded(int status_code);
```

from a diff like this:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/builtin-http-fetch.c b/http-fetch.c
similarity index 95%
rename from builtin-http-fetch.c
rename to http-fetch.c
index f3e63d7..e8f44ba 100644
--- a/builtin-http-fetch.c
+++ b/http-fetch.c
@@ -1,8 +1,9 @@
 #include "cache.h"
 #include "walker.h"
 
-int cmd_http_fetch(int argc, const char **argv, const char *prefix)
+int main(int argc, const char **argv)
 {
+       const char *prefix;
        struct walker *walker;
        int commits_on_stdin = 0;
        int commits;
@@ -18,6 +19,8 @@ int cmd_http_fetch(int argc, const char **argv, const char *prefix)
        int get_verbosely = 0;
        int get_recover = 0;
 
+       prefix = setup_git_directory();
+
        git_config(git_default_config, NULL);
 
        while (arg < argc && argv[arg][0] == '-') {
diff --git a/fetch.h b/fetch.h
index 5fd3e65..d43e0ca 100644
--- a/fetch.h
+++ b/fetch.h
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 #include "config.h"
 #include "http.h"
 
-int cmd_http_fetch(int argc, const char **argv, const char *prefix);
+int main(int argc, const char **argv);
 
 void start_fetch(const char* uri);
 bool fetch_succeeded(int status_code);
```

If you only want to show added/removed/modified lines, and not the surrounding context, you can pass `-U0` to git diff:

```
$ git diff -U0 | diff-lines
http-fetch.c:4:-int cmd_http_fetch(int argc, const char **argv, const char *prefix)
http-fetch.c:4:+int main(int argc, const char **argv)
http-fetch.c:6:+       const char *prefix;
http-fetch.c:22:+       prefix = setup_git_directory();
http-fetch.c:23:+
fetch.h:4:-int cmd_http_fetch(int argc, const char **argv, const char *prefix);
fetch.h:4:+int main(int argc, const char **argv);
```

It's robust against ANSI color codes, so you can pass `--color=always` to git diff to get the usual color coding for added/removed lines.

The output can be easily grepped:

```
$ git diff -U0 | diff-lines | grep 'main'
http-fetch.c:4:+int main(int argc, const char **argv)
fetch.h:4:+int main(int argc, const char **argv);
```

In your case `git diff -U0` would give:

```
$ git diff -U0 | diff-lines
test.txt:2:+new line here
test.txt:3:+another new line
test.txt:6:-will be removed
test.txt:6:-git repo
test.txt:6:+git
```

If you just want the line numbers, change the `echo "$path:$line:$REPLY"` to just `echo "$line"` and pipe the output through `uniq`.

Comment: How could I pass-through bash color escape codes?  This is great, but the color codes coming from `git diff --color` do not come through.  Or do you think it would be better just to add the color escapes into the return from this function?

Comment: I updated the function so the various regexes are robust to ANSI color codes. `git diff --color | diff-lines` now works as expected :)

Comment: This solution works awesome! it should be marked as the answer as it really does what the OP asked. If it worked for you please up vote it so we can make it the popular answer :)

Comment: I keep getting this error using zsh: `zsh: parse error near \`]+m'` Any ideas? The error comes from this line: `elif [[ $REPLY =~ ^($esc\[[0-9;]+m)*([\ +-]) ]]; then`

Comment: @HoshSadiq Simply quoting the regular expression seems to have worked.

Comment: Gives erroneous numbering when a single added line is broken down into multiple lines using "\". This script increments the line number by just 1 whereas I added 10 lines (say).

https://github.com/jay/showlinenum works fine!

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I needed! Have been searching a lot for this!

Comment: @SaheelGodhane I don't quite get it. If you use \ it's still a new line, no? Sure, as interpreted by bash it's not, but git diff works on the files interpreted as text files, so if you hit enter it's a new line?
Asking to understand this shortcoming

Comment: @IceFire looks like we are saying the same thing. I added 10 lines, separated by "\" but the script will say I added only 1 line. To be honest, it's 8 years since I used this so I might be misunderstanding my own comment.

Comment: @SaheelGodhane ah, strange... this script does not explicitly check if there is \ and then change the count, it just relies on git diff. So if git diff does not join lines by \, I am puzzled where this should come from. Will keep an open eye on it anyways, thanks! And yeah, that's a bit time where things can be forgotten :)

Answer (score 23):

I use the `--unified=0` option of `git diff`.

For example, `git diff --unified=0 commit1 commit2` outputs the diff:

[image: *enter image description here*]

Because of the `--unified=0` option, the diff output shows 0 context lines; in other words, it shows *exactly the changed lines*.

Now, you can identify the lines that start with '@@', and parse it based on the pattern:

`@@ -startline1,count1 +startline2,count2 @@`

Back to the above example, for the file WildcardBinding.java, start from line 910, 0 lines are deleted. Start from line 911, 4 lines are added.

Comment: what if `@@ -910,10,+911,15@@ ` or something, then how do we say exactly how many number of lines being added, deleted or modified

Comment: Do you have a good way to output the line numbers in a list like OP asked for?

Answer (score 7):

I had this same problem so I wrote a gawk script that changes the output of git diff to prepend the line number for each line. I find it useful sometimes when I need to diff working tree, although it's not limited to that. Maybe it is useful to someone here?

```
$ git diff HEAD~1 |showlinenum.awk
diff --git a/doc.txt b/doc.txt
index fae6176..6ca8c26 100644
--- a/doc.txt
+++ b/doc.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
1: red
2: blue
 :-green
3:+yellow
```

You can download it from here:
https://github.com/jay/showlinenum

Comment: Looks very handy.  Keep in mind this code has the advantage (or disadvantage) of being GPL licensed.

Comment: [I wrote `git diffn`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455377/git-diff-with-line-numbers-git-log-with-line-numbers/61997003#61997003) to do this too, and it fully retains terminal colors and shows the line numbers of both the old file on the left and the new file on the right.

Answer (score 4):

Line numbers of all uncommitted lines (added/modified):

```
git blame <file> | grep -n '^0\{8\} ' | cut -f1 -d:
```

Example output:

```
1
2
8
12
13
14
```

Comment: what about the contents of the lines that were changed as well?

Answer (score 2):

Configure an external diff tool which will show you the line numbers. For example, this is what I have in my git global config:

```
diff.guitool=kdiff3
difftool.kdiff3.path=c:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
difftool.kdiff3.cmd="c:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/q/949242/526535

Comment: isn't there any other way to get these info without using diff tool. Only using git commands?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bash function I cobbled together:

```
echo ${f}:
for n in $(git --no-pager blame --line-porcelain $1 |
        awk '/author Not Committed Yet/{if (a && a !~ /author Not Committed Yet/) print a} {a=$0}' |
        awk '{print $3}') ; do
    if (( prev_line > -1 )) ; then
        if (( "$n" > (prev_line + 1) )) ; then
            if (( (prev_line - range_start) > 1 )) ; then
                echo -n "$range_start-$prev_line,"
            else
                echo -n "$range_start,$prev_line,"
            fi
            range_start=$n
        fi
    else
        range_start=$n
    fi
    prev_line=$n
done
if (( "$range_start" != "$prev_line" )) ; then
    echo "$range_start-$prev_line"
else
    echo "$range_start"
fi
```

And it ends up looking like this:

```
views.py:
403,404,533-538,546-548,550-552,554-559,565-567,580-582
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git diff` coupled with `shortstat` parameter to just show the **no of** lines changed.

For the no of lines changed (in a file that's already in the repo) since your last commit

```
git diff HEAD --shortstat
```

It'll output something similar to

```
1 file changed, 4 insertions(+)
```

Comment: The question asks for the line numbers for each line that has been changed, not a total of how many lines have been changed.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a fairly accurate count of changed lines:

```
git diff --word-diff <commit> |egrep '(?:\[-)|(?:\{\+)' |wc -l
```

Also, here is a solution for line numbers in your diff: https://github.com/jay/showlinenum

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a way to output only the lines changed for each file using git diff.
My idea was to feed this output to a linter for type checking. [This is what helped me](https://gist.github.com/mdawaffe/529e6b3ee820e777c2cfd2f8255d187f)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you were asking for, but `git blame TEXTFILE` may help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some Python copypasta to get the line numbers for modified / removed lines, in case you came across this question looking for that.

It should be fairly easy to modify it into something that gets the modified and added line numbers as well.

I've only tested on Windows, but it should be cross platform as well.

```py
import re
import subprocess

def main(file1: str, file2: str):
    diff = get_git_diff(file1, file2)
    print(edited_lines(diff))

def edited_lines(git_diff: str):
    ans = []
    diff_lines = git_diff.split("\n")
    found_first = False
    # adjust for added lines
    adjust = 0
    # how many lines since the start
    count = 0
    for line in diff_lines:
        if found_first:
            count += 1
            if line.startswith('-'):
                # minus one because count is 1 when we're looking at the start line
                ans.append(start + count - adjust - 1)
                continue

            if line.startswith('+'):
                adjust += 1
                continue

        # get the start line
        match = re.fullmatch(r'@@ \-(\d+),\d+ \+\d+,\d+ @@', line)
        if match:
            start = int(match.group(1))
            count = 0
            adjust = 0
            found_first = True

    return ans


def get_git_diff(file1: str, file2: str):
    try:
        diff_process: subprocess.CompletedProcess = subprocess.run(['git', 'diff', '--no-index', '-u', file1, file2], shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        ans = diff_process.stdout
    # git may exit with 1 even though it worked
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        if e.stdout and e.stderr is None:
            ans = e.stdout
        else:
            raise

    # remove carriage at the end of lines from Windows
    ans = ans.decode()
    ans.replace('\r', '')
    return ans


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main("file1.txt", "file2.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this, credit goes to Jakub Bochenski - [Git diff with line numbers (Git log with line numbers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455377/git-diff-with-line-numbers-git-log-with-line-numbers#comment89402621_24456418)

`git diff --unified=0 | grep -Po '^\+\+\+ ./\K.*|^@@ -[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)? \+\K[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?(?= @@)'`

Comment: `grep: invalid option -- P`

Comment: @TayJen as usually it might depend on a specific grep version as its like with many different cli tools, specific flag might be in that or another version, for me it works.